# Which OS X Applications do you find indispensable?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

### Please Search Prior To Posting!

There are *many* applications already listed.  In all likelihood, this includes the one you are thinking of. Please check the existing answers to avoid duplicates, and the resulting cleanup it necessitates.

To search, use the search box in the upper-right corner. To search the answers of the current question, use `inquestion:this`. For example:

```
inquestion:this Evernote
```

If it hasn't already been posted, please follow a few simple rules when adding it as an answer.

#### Rules

1. Limit to **one application per answer**.
2. Add a **short description** of the application.
3. Add a **link to the website** in the name of the application if possible (no direct downloads).
4. Use **`## [appName](link)`** for citing the application name.
5. Only **Mac OS X** (not iOS, OS 9, compatible, etc) applications. All versions of OS X are accepted, but if the application requires a *specific* version please note.

Comment: Voted to close — a good question, but we really should avoid subjective ones here.

Comment: @Apostlion: Simply because it's subjective does not mean it can't be answered. There are (community defined) "good" applications that are useful on a daily basis.

Comment: @Josh K — true, but it's a StackExchange policy not to allow them — as you see, [subjective] is now disallowed as a tag across SO-family websites due to the consensus being that the questions only add clutter to the Q&A site.

Comment: @Josh K: I disagree... I think that questions should always be able to be "answered".  I realize that many questions can have multiple right answers, but when a question is this subjective, every single answer from ever single user could theoretically be correct.

Comment: @calavera: You must concede that it is not always the case. Simply because there are many "theoretically" correct answers does not preclude it from being good question. We want good questions.

Comment: This discussion should be continued on meta, but I think it is the _subjective_ tag that was banned, not subjective questions.  The feeling was that the tag didn't add anything.

Comment: Voted to reopen - it is subjective, but a popular and useful style of question, if kept as a wiki and not repeated too much. These questions are mostly accepted on gadgets.stackexhange.com for example.

Comment: The problem with subjective questions is they lose relevance much more readily. The answer to a specific problem generally remains the same as the days go on. The answers to a subjective question such as this generally become less relevant in the face of time. A new user coming across an un-pruned thread may be lead astray because a once revered piece of software has fallen in disgrace or otherwise been supplanted by a superior tool, but the only way they would know this is if they read all X number of pages to the thread.

Comment: Can we make this Community Wiki? And also 1 app per answer?
Much easier to check if something has already been said and to edit to add information about said app. Thank you.

Comment: @Loic: Good point, I noticed it has been reopened.

Comment: I did a lot of cleanup. Changed all the app names to `##` (because it was the most commonly used in the existing answers. Moved links so that they were within the app names.  Removed some first-person descriptors.

Comment: http://osx.iusethis.com/

Comment: @muddybulldog, what makes you think this would be "un-pruned"? A poll like this can very much be dynamic and "alive", because we have 1) the voting system, 2) ability to edit posts, and 3) possibility to add new answers when new great apps appear!

Comment: @jonik: Even I have seen the light, this thread rocks :)

Comment: There's now a question on meta dealing with this: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90/list-of-x-poll-style-questions-what-to-do

Comment: Is there a way to "search prior to posting" through all pages at once? - nevermind just found a way: **searching on the question feed**!  :)

Comment: This is an exemplary community wiki. Thanks to everyone involved.

Comment: @Cawas: i added another way to search the answers into the question.  It involves using `inquestion:this` in the search field.

Comment: @calavera woot! (I think) I wish I could just add features like that. :D

Comment: @Calavera `inquestion:this` search is **case sensitive**. for example try this, `inquestion:this iterm`, you won't get any results, but if you try `inquestion:this iTerm` you will find one entry. Is this expected behavior or can I create a Bug/ Feature req on Meta ?

Comment: @garikapat: i would create a bug on meta... feel free to edit the question with a note about this as well

Comment: i don't have the time or motivation to go through and remove *all* the entries that have had some sort of price notation added to the heading.  did the first page, please help if you can.  adding price into the heading is ridiculous... prices are fluid and easily become out of date.  i'm not opposed to mentioning price in the body, but in the heading it makes this list look amateur hour.

Comment: This is no different from [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41969/what-input-devices-do-you-find-to-be-an-indespensable-part-of-using-your-mac), which was just closed.

Comment: @MatthewRead The difference is we close hardware shopping questions in almost all cases and we don't close software recommendation questions in almost all cases. There have been some [meta] discussions about either locking or closing or deleting questions like this that fail to be maintained and become stale / out dated.

Answer (score 230):

### [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/)

Put your files into your Dropbox on one computer, and they'll be instantly available on any of your other computers that you've installed Dropbox on.

Comment: Not just Mac though.

Comment: @Moshe: Sure, many of the apps mentioned (VLC, Chrome, Skype, Evernote, ...) aren't *only* available for Mac. That doesn't matter.

Comment: I find it surprising dropbox comes up first... This would never happen with a "Windows Programs you can't live without" in a windows community.

Comment: @Cawas - Maybe because Dropbox has Mac spirit: it just works.

Comment: It is of note that Dropbox has had a sordid history with security and underhanded practices that involve dealing with authorities: http://news.cnet.com/8301-31921_3-20072755-281/dropbox-confirms-security-glitch-no-password-required/ and http://paranoia.dubfire.net/2011/04/how-dropbox-sacrifices-user-privacy-for.html

Comment: Dropbox is also the number one in data leak from within enterprise networks. I wouldn't advise a friend to use Dropbox for important data.

Comment: I cant live without Dropbox and Logmein for that matter. The best 1 2 punch in the Biz

Answer (score 220):

### [Terminal](http://www.apple.com/osx/apps/all.html#terminal)

Terminal.app opens a UNIX terminal and allows you to access many power-user tools and features, just as you would on a machine running Linux or BSD.

Comment: Ditto. Open permanently and the main reason I moved from PC's - a decent unix access point.

Comment: iTerm is even better.

Comment: What about iTerm2 ?

Comment: Visor is a great addition--a keystroke slides your terminal in from the top of the screen.

Comment: @Studer - iTerm2 is about the most excellent Terminal I've ever used. (except perhaps GLTerminal ;) )

Comment: Forget terminal + visor. iTerm 2 offers visor plus much much more... Switched to few weeks ago, will never go back.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up - iTerm2 looks like a great alternative!

Answer (score 182):

### [Preview](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/apps-and-utilities.html#preview)

A lot of people (especially newcomers) completely overlook what the humble built-in Preview app can do. Apart from handling PDFs (including printing them in various layouts etc), you can join PDF files together with it (open the sidebar and start dragging pdf files into it, rearrange pages etc).

You can crop & resize images, adjust colour & saturation (etc), save as different image format and even add text & simple diagrammatical annotations to pictures.

Like a lot of the built-in software, there's an awful lot of flexibility that you simply don't appreciate at first because it's hidden in the GUI - as opposed to huge nested menus of functions, you have to try things with the mouse - often things just work!

Comment: @robsoft: I didn't know about the joining of PDFs.
Can you explain how this happens? (Or am I misunderstanding you?) IE: document1.pdf and document2.pdf and then save it out as a merged document.pdf?

I've tried the obvious stuff and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Cameron - sure, I didn't get this at first. It's not totally intuitive. First, open a PDF document. Press Shift-Cmd-D (or select View Sidebar from View menu). Now drag another PDF file (from Finder, Desktop etc) onto the PDF file you can see in the sidebar (drop your 2nd doc on top of the 1st, not into blank area of sidebar). Preview will join the documents together (you can revert, or save, save as, etc). All of the pdf stuff seems to be driven through the sidebar. Let me know if you get it, otherwise I'll try make a little online tutorial. :-)

Comment: That's brilliant! No longer do I have to wait for bloated Acrobat to open do merge documents.

My issue was I opened both PDFs up at once, which stuck them both in the sidebar as separate PDFs, and wouldn't let me do it. Trick is to just open the one, and then do the dragging.

Thanks much!

Comment: awesome! I didn't know either about the merging. Why would they hide it that much?

Comment: I remember how much I hated preview back in 10.4 days! Now, thanks to the fact that Quicklook took over some of his duties, I love it :)

Comment: Also worth noting... you can annotate pdfs using Preview. This is useful for all sorts of things; adding simple shapes to highlight/emphasize things, adding (colored) text for note-taking, etc.

Comment: Merging - oh, nice!  And here I was just a java program ("PDFSAM" for "PDF Split And Merge") for that!

Comment: I like JustLooking (http://chipmunkninja.com/JustLooking).  Navigates more easily through a directory of files, and actually shows animations!

Comment: And for the adventurous one, you can use Automator to script some tasks.

Comment: A shortcut that many people seem to have missed is Print Selected Page, option-cmd-P, in 10.6 and later.

Answer (score 158):

### [Growl](http://growl.info/)

Growl is a well-known 'notification' system for the Mac; many different programs support Growl and will pass notifications to it. You have a surprising degree of control over how the notifications appear, how they group themselves together, how they are dismissed from the screen etc. This can be configured universally or on an app-by-app basis, so it's very flexible.

One of the most useful features for me has been the way you can configure it to send notifications to selected other Macs on the network - I can leave one of my Macs doing something (such as downloading a large file) while I'm using my other Mac, and when the first Mac has finished doing its stuff the notification will pop-up on the Mac I'm in front of.

Growl is free, though you can donate to the cause!

Programs that can use Growl include Coda, Dropbox, Firefox, Handbrake, NetNewsWire, SuperDuper!, Transmit, and also Mail & Safari (via helper plugins).

Comment: Ugh, I can not express to you how much I loath Growl. It's even worse that tons of apps (like Dropbox) install it silently without asking, or simply crash and burn (like Max) if it isn't installed without giving you any error messages or means of troubleshooting.

Comment: Cannot live without Growl!

Comment: @Bryson what I like about Growl is that it gives a central place where I can control all notifications for apps, whether I want them to pop up or just "shut up about it". I'm surprised that Apple didn't add a standard Notification system to Lion, it seems like centralizing this should be the role of the OS.

Comment: @Bryson Both of those issues are the fault of the apps in question, there's not a lot Growl can do about apps not using it properly.

Comment: And Growl is no longer free, it costs $1.99 now at App Store.

Comment: Apps no longer need to have Growl installed in order to use Growl notifications, so users would only need to purchase it if they want to customize their notifications. This also means apps no longer need to secretly install Growl. More info on their [note to developers](http://growl.info/notetodevelopers). Growl is still open source, too, and there's a link to the source code on that page as well.

Answer (score 139):

### [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/)

Google Chrome is a lightweight, minimalistic web browser based off the open source project, [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/).

Comment: Though some Firefox features still aren't matched in Chrome, I nowadays find myself mostly using Chrome on OS X because it's just so much faster.

Comment: before firefox4 i had moved almost completely to chrome, but yay for ff4 (esp. tab grouping)

Comment: [Quote of the day](https://twitter.com/Tisca/status/29304574565): "I just ditched Firefox for Chrome. I feel like I just left my wife and kids for a 19 year old cheerleader."

Comment: After switching to chrome a while ago, I've noticed it still has trouble with two things:  CPU usage with HD flash video, and ASP driven interfaces (and other Microsoft languages).

Comment: Chrome has also had a lot of trouble with caching (specifically clearing cache) in the recent releases. As a web developer, it's a huge problem. I'm on the verge of moving back to FF.

Comment: After Lion came out, I switched to Safari because Chrome is way too slow at adapting the goodness.

Comment: As "lightweight" as the interface may lead you to believe, Chrome is VERY resource intensive.

Comment: "lightweight" is not the word I used. It hase been edited by someone else ;-) @XAleXOwnZX

Answer (score 133):

### [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

"The missing package manager for OS X". Like MacPorts and Fink, but simpler to use and easy to contribute to.

Comment: Beats MacPorts and Fink right out the water!

Comment: I love homebrew. Much better than MacPorts. Uses existing libraries that come with OS X to cut down compile times.

Comment: Soon to be not so missing when the Mac app store comes out... :-P

Comment: @Ricket: I think those are orthogonal. Homebrew is for CLI Open Source programs.

Comment: @Ricket - It will never make the app store. It has too much functionality that significantly violates the (ridiculous) app store guidelines.

Comment: @FakeName, yep. But I wrote that November of last year, when the app store had been announced but I don't believe details had really been released. I was probably of the naive impression that the app store might actually be good and not as policed as it turned out to be. Also I had just bought my first Mac probably a week or two before that comment (though I was consuming Apple and OS X information at an incredible rate) so that might have something to do with it.

Comment: The install script does not seem to work under lion?

Answer (score 131):

### [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/)

A good IDE for cocoa developers. Xcode 5 is now available on the Mac App Store.

Comment: It's a great IDE, and it's FREE.

Comment: @Warren P: Well, Xcode 4 isn’t free.

Comment: @Mathias Well.. They say that if you pay up the developer's licence it is? (not that I would call that free, but still)

Comment: Xcode4 is free again.

Comment: Give AppCode a try - lots of refactoring and editing conveniences

Comment: Xcode is great. It is the reason I got a Mac.

Comment: Xcode includes a lot of other stuff, like a .plist editor and command line tools. Instruments app (that uses dtrace) is an awesome tool for peeping into your Mac. And it's free from the App Store.

Comment: That's the only reason I bought a Mac. Though after buying I got to know how good a mac can be.

Answer (score 130):

### [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

At its simplest, it's a video player that'll play nearly anything.  File extensions supported include: mov, mkv, flv, wmv.

It's actually considerably more powerful than that in terms of streaming and converting, but even as a straight up video player, it's impressive.

Comment: I really can't stand VLC.  Buggy, extremely difficult to configure, ugly as hades... the only thing it has going for it is the sheer number of different formats it will play.  Why should I have to be an expert in video and audio codecs to configure my player?  Movist beats this one by far.

Comment: I've never had luck with VLC. It is constantly crashing, and terribly buggy. Seconding Movist a hundred times.

Comment: I always loved VLC... but try MPlayer guys. It's listed here already and it's awesome!

Comment: Never configured anything on VLC, it works for me out of the box, with flv, wmv, mkv, mp4, avi, mov, mpeg. Unexpected crashes do happen, you have to deal with it, but other than that, it's great.

Comment: Use MplayerX for Mac, it's free on Mac App Store. Although i prefer the command line version mplayer

Comment: Agree with Petruza, I've installed VLC on OSX multiple times, zero problems.

Comment: VLC is ugly. [MPlayerX](http://mplayerx.org/) is so much more Mac-spirited.

Comment: VLC is ugly since the version 2 update

Comment: @Lamnk Even MplayerOSX Extended regarded as the future of MPlayerX available at http://www.mplayerosx.ch/

Answer (score 126):

### [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password)

1Password can create strong, unique passwords for you, remember them, and restore them, all directly in your web browser.

Comment: +100 I can't even remember my password now

Comment: I use PasswordWallet for the same thing, but either seems crucial.

Comment: LastPass does the same thing for a lot less money, and it's available cross-platform (including Linux) so you can keep your passwords synced regardless of where you are and what system you're on.

Answer (score 116):

### [TextMate](http://macromates.com/)

*TextMate brings Apple's approach to operating systems into the world of text editors. By bridging UNIX underpinnings and GUI, TextMate cherry-picks the best of both worlds to the benefit of expert scripters and novice users alike.*

If you’re looking for a good editor, Sublime Text 2 is quite good too by now!

Comment: TextMate 2.0 is the new Duke Nukem Forever ;-)

Comment: It's funny, Textmate, along with a browser and Terminal is open almost all the time on my desktop, but whilst it's a great text editor I could 'live' with the alternatives.

Comment: The CMD T shortcut would be hard for me to live without.

Comment: @neoneye, that's why I use the Command-T (Mac)VIM extension :)

Comment: If you're into TextMate, have a look at [Sublime Text 2](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82/which-os-x-applications-do-you-find-indispensable/11672#11672). You won't be disappointed.

Comment: Sublime Text 2 is extremely fast. It's actively developed too.

Answer (score 109):

### **[Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/)**

> Alfred is a productivity application for Mac OS X, which aims to save you time in searching your local computer and the web. Whether it's maps, Amazon, eBay, Wikipedia, you can feed your web addiction quicker than ever before.

It's a wonderful piece because it enables you to:

- Increase your productivity by launching apps with shortcuts
- Instant access to web searches, bookmarks & more
- Browse and play music from your iTunes library quickly
- Perform actions – copy, move & email files & folders
- Ward off RSI – skip using the mouse with easy shortcuts

Comment: Buy the 'PowerPack' for this - it adds even more functionality. Alfred is a really nice little utility - replaced QuickSilver for me.

Comment: @robsoft I'd *love* to buy the PowerPack to support Alfred, but I'm afraid that if I do this, it'll get too complicated. (File control, iTunes, ...) I like Alfred the way it is right now.

Comment: Best powerpack feature: clipboard history. I can now "copy up" three things, then paste them back out in whatever order I like. Brillig!

Comment: My best friend.

Comment: I love Alfred. I switched from Quicksilver, though I'm admittedly not a QS poweruser.

Comment: Alfred is pretty sweet

Answer (score 106):

### [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

HandBrake is an open-source, GPL-licensed, multiplatform, multithreaded video transcoder.

Comment: Although it *still* doesn't support drag-and-drop, which is incredibly frustrating. I usually end up using the now-unsupported VisualHub.

Comment: Handbrake is awesome, I use it with mythbuntu

Answer (score 105):

### [Adium](http://adium.im)

Adium is a free **instant messaging application** for Mac OS X that can connect to AIM, MSN, Jabber, Yahoo, and more. It provides enhanced security by supporting the OTR messaging protocol out of the box.

Comment: Adium is not needed anymore starting with Lion :)

Comment: @Sorin Why is that? I don't think iChat will be able to connect to all those accounts cl.ly/87Ii

Comment: It can do many! Even Facebook. Yeah not all of them but some of those are pretty obscure. I must say the iChat updates in Lion made me ditch Adium.

Answer (score 98):

### [Perian](http://perian.org/)

*Perian is a free, open source QuickTime component that adds native support for many popular video formats.*

Comment: Perian developers decided to cease any further development on Perian. There won't be any new releases or fixes for MKV support if nobody stakes over.

Answer (score 95):

### [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/)

Transmission is a cross-platform BitTorrent client that is:
Free and Community-Driven.
Easy.
Lean.
Native.
Powerful.

Comment: +1, Transmission rocks. For those with servers there is even a slick web-ui.

Comment: Great simple app.

Answer (score 92):

### [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html)

The Unarchiver is a much more capable replacement for "BOMArchiveHelper.app", the built-in archive unpacker program in Mac OS X. The Unarchiver is designed to handle many more formats than BOMArchiveHelper, and to better fit in with the design of the Finder. It can also handle filenames in foreign character sets, created with non-English versions of other operating systems.

Supported file formats include Zip, Tar-GZip, Tar-BZip2, RAR, 7-zip, LhA, StuffIt and many other more and less obscure formats.

Comment: The Unarchiver team also provide a command line utility `urar` that uses the same compression library, so you can extract all those obscure formats from a script.

Comment: Can't handle everything I've thrown at it (sometimes chokes on password protected zips/rars, or split rars that may have been created on Windows(?), but I have a few backups in case.  This is my default archive extract utility.

Answer (score 88):

### [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/)

*Caffeine is a tiny program that puts an icon in the right side of your menu bar. Click it to prevent your Mac from automatically going to sleep, dimming the screen or starting screen savers. Click it again to go back. Right-click (or ^-click) the icon to show the menu.*

Comment: I use [InsomniaX](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/22211/insomniax) - any idea how it compares to Caffeine?

Comment: I've never really understood these.  When do you want this?

Comment: @khedron: it's useful for long-running unattended tasks e.g. download program, compiler, video encoding, some long computation, ... anything that doesn't require interaction but takes long enough time that your Mac would sleep otherwise.

Comment: @khedron I got Caffeine so that I could watch videos on my computer without the screen dimming. I had had enough of wiggling the mouse every few minutes.

Comment: @joshdick: I use [Jiggler](http://www.sticksoftware.com/software/Jiggler.html) for that.

Comment: It's ⌃-click, not ⌘-click.

Comment: I up-voted the comment about InsomniaX but actually wanted to recommend [InsomniaX 2.0 – Built for Lion](http://semaja2.net/archives/206) from the same developer - makes it easy to run clamshell mode on Snow-Leopard with external display

Answer (score 83):

### [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/)

*FTP, SFTP, Amazon S3 and WebDav client.*

Comment: Transmit 4 is awesome. I used Cyberduck for a long time, but I recently checked out Transmit 4 and was quite impressed.

Comment: Transmit + Textmate are two apps I really can't do without. If Panic could ever get their act together and make Coda a serious contender for Textmate AND make the FTP as good as Transmit (why not, it's a Transmit app) then Coda would rule them all. But not today.

Answer (score 82):

### [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/)

for Upload, Download and Sync of FTP, SFTP, WebDav, iCloud, S3, ...

Comment: open-source and great

Comment: honestly i got really frustrated with cyberduck due to little but important details (for example your bookmarks aren't sortable, no sidebyside view local/remote, ...) and switched to Transmit. Haven't looked back since ...

Comment: At first i loved it, but from time to time SFTP synchronization fails with "nothing to do" even when there are modified files.

Comment: CyberDuck even supports Amazon S3 (cloud storage).

Comment: I'm frustated with CyberDuck, it delays to be updated when Goole Docs change some API.

Answer (score 82):

### [Skype](http://www.skype.com)

With skype, you can make

- Voice and video calls to anyone else on Skype
- Conference calls with three or more people
- Instant messaging, file transfer and screen sharing

Comment: + Yahoo Messenger, AIM and iChat don't support Voice/Video chat with Windows clients. For me, the only choice for Video/Voice is Skype.

Comment: Sadly, Beta 5 is as awful as a UI can get.

Comment: The problem with skype now is that was bought from Microsoft. I don't think they will be keeping good. I'm waiting for some Google response offered in Brazil.

Answer (score 81):

### [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)

*The MacPorts Project is an open-source community initiative to design an easy-to-use system for compiling, installing, and upgrading either command-line, X11 or Aqua based open-source software on the Mac OS X operating system. To that end we provide the command-line driven MacPorts software package under a BSD License, and through it easy access to thousands of ports that greatly simplify the task of compiling and installing open-source software on your Mac.*

Comment: what about homebrew and fink?

Comment: I would recommend Homebrew over MacPorts by a long way. https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Comment: Giving this a down-vote because there's an answer about Homebrew and I want it bubbled up to the top. If others think the same, please up- and down-vote accordingly.

Comment: Homebrew will kick macport's ass anyday

Comment: I down-voted MacPorts and up-voted Homebrew. Homebrew is a lifesaver.

Answer (score 81):

### [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)

A very good port of Vim. I used both Emacs and TextMate for quite some time, but finally became a Vim user. I think I'll have a look at TextMate 2, if it will actually be released some time…

Comment: I also recently discovered the GUI port of vim for the Mac, and I must say I really love editing C and C++ code in it. It also helps to better edit makefiles, since Xcode hasn't really got any support for makefiles. I only write Objective-C code in my Xcode editor, since Xcode has phenomenal text completion for Cocoa and the vim editor lacks this.

Comment: I cannot believe that TextMate is above MacVim. Keep voting people. Hopefully this question does not get closed soon.

Answer (score 77):

### [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/)

More then just an application launcher, Quicksilver is an intuitive, self learning, application launcher and system manipulator.

It can also assign global hotkeys to actions, store clipboard history, show the current iTunes song and much more.

Comment: what quicksilver does?

Comment: Quicksilver is an intuitive, self learning, application launcher and system manipulator. Best I can phrase it.

Comment: @josh could make your answer community wiki, please?

Comment: @josh I removed TextMate since there's already an answer with it and made Adium a separate one.

Comment: @Loic: That's fine.

Comment: For similar options, also look at Google Quick Search Box. Apple's Spotlight now has many of the more interesting Quicksilver features as well.

Comment: if spotlight would appear in the middle of my screen, I'd be almost happy, but Quicksilver is still way much better for launching apps

Comment: @John: Quicksilver is still faster (on all machines I've tried) then Spotlight.

Comment: “I’m inclined to encourage users to move over to
the more stable and well supported alternatives like LaunchBar” – [Nicholas Jitkoff, Developer of Quicksilver](http://lifehacker.com/software/exclusive-lifehacker-interview/quicksilvers-creator-on-the-future-of-qs-330548.php)

Comment: @Carmine: I say no to LB. Quicksilver is free, and *does much more*. Besides, where's the fun without a little application instability?

Comment: I was used to Launchy from Windows world, and found Quicksilver. But after few days, I found that Spotlight works just fine for me and I never use Quicksilver. It was also pretty hard to find shortcut that didn't collide with some other program that I use.

Comment: I used Quicksilver for a long time, but I think Launchbar has the edge at this point.

Comment: Never understood why I should use an app to do what Spotlight already does. I understand people using Quicksilver from before Spotlight existed, but I don't see any reason to switch for new users. Is there one?

Comment: Quicksilver has some scripts built into it--it's more than just a Search tool, from what I recall.  I think there were some iTunes plugins, and other application extensions.  Where Spotlight is great for searching and launching files/applications (what I use it for), Quicksilver can do more automations I believe.

Comment: I LOVE Quicksilver. I use it all the time!!!!!! Not only for Spotlight-like capabilities, but many other things.

Comment: There are some unique things that Quicksilver does, where you can chain things together to create a subject-verb-object kind of construct in one command, like "upload X to Y using Z". That said, it's been years since I used it and I prefer using the terminal for stuff like that.

Comment: QS can even open new Control/Observe sessions for remote computers from Apple Remote Desktop.  It's not just an app launcher, it's an anything launcher.

Comment: I use this so much every day. One of the things I love is the easy hotkeying. For example I have a hotkey that runs an applescript that opens a new tab in Chrome so I can do websearches or visit websites with autocompletion.

Comment: Spotlight and Quicksilver are two different beasts. Quicksilver allows you to match entries in your catalog with a few keystrokes, and spotlight allows you to search your computer for words. If you type "sp" in Quicksilver you might get "**S**ystem **P**references" if you use that a lot, or "**S**teve **P**orter" if you send him a lot of mails/IMs. Spotlight will just show you all things with "sp" in their name or contents

Comment: An example subject-verb-object action: moving files. Select a few files, hit ⌘-⎋ (escape), Tab, type "move", Tab, then type a few chars of the destination and Return. Quicksilver moves the files then redisplays with the moved files in the subject, so you can open them or 'reveal' them in Finder (or any other supported verb). Way faster than dragging through nested Finder windows.

Answer (score 71):

### [iWork](http://www.apple.com/iwork/)

> Pages is both a streamlined word processor and an easy-to-use page layout tool. It allows you to be a writer one minute and a designer the next, always with a perfect document in the works.

> With great-looking templates, easy-to-create formulas, and dynamic tables and charts, spreadsheets suddenly make perfect sense.

> Create your presentation in Keynote, and you’ll be a hard act to follow. Powerful yet easy-to-use tools and dazzling effects put the show in slideshow.

I use iWork constantly. Both on my Mac and iPad. It's just great :D

Comment: At work I have use Word, however I write my text in Pages and then export to Word. Pages is a well crafted product.

Comment: I love Pages to make beautiful cards! You can't beat the simple yet effective layouting that's possible with this software.

Comment: Personally I think Excel is more powerful than Numbers, or at least the power is not hidden.

Comment: Excel is hugely more powerful (Pivot tables for a start), but it, and it's output, is nowhere near as pretty as Numbers.

Comment: And it is much cheaper than MS Office!

Comment: Also now available on the iPhone 4 as well. Very handy.

Comment: @Bryson indeed, and I'm already using it. :)

Comment: I really tried to use iWork, but I just can't. The support for more advanced features - like multiple Tables of Contents - just isn't there. It's a slick piece of software for more uses though.

Comment: To me, iWork is the Fisher Price of Office. I tried making a simple graph in Numbers, and I soon found it to be impossible. It's decent for the iPad and others, though.

Comment: Should really separate this into its components. I find Keynote is superior to PowerPoint (except when you need to interchange with Windows folks), but that's just about it. Numbers doesn't hold a candle against Excel whereas Pages is so-so.

Answer (score 70):

### [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)

VirtualBox is a powerful x86 and AMD64/Intel64 virtualization product for enterprise as well as home use. Not only is VirtualBox an extremely feature rich, high performance product for enterprise customers, it is also the only professional solution that is freely available as Open Source Software under the terms of the GNU General Public License (GPL).

Comment: VirtualBox is just plain awesome.

Comment: could make your answer community wiki, please?

Comment: Especially as it is the only solution to virtualize Mac OS X (although restricted to Mac hardware only).

Answer (score 67):

### [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com)

Evernote is an app for note taking that features online syncing, much like Dropbox. Install Evernote on your desktop, laptop, iPhone and iPad and have access to all your notes, and if you've left all them all at home, access them on the web.

Comment: Evernote is amazing. +10

Comment: Evernote is now available on the [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/fi/app/evernote/id406056744?mt=12). (Which, by the way, has resulted in a [huge influx](http://blog.evernote.com/2011/01/07/mac-app-store-more-than-doubles-new-users/) of new users.)

Answer (score 66):

### [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/)

While I adore Chrome, but Chrome on Mac is not on the same level as Chrome on Windows yet.

Comment: It's getting there!

Comment: The Dev tools in Safari (some say the same) are just not there yet so I stick with Chrome for Dev. If Apple update Safari in the next release then we will see.

Comment: Safari get stuck sometimes =[

Comment: Safari integrates better with the whole OS X Lion experience

Answer (score 63):

### [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/personal.html)

Firefox is an open-source web browser from Mozilla, based off Netscape.

With a [few OS X specific tweaks](http://sdfjkl.org/post/2013/03/07/Making-Firefox-behave-on-OS-X) it can be made to behave like a OS X browser should, including font rendering, Keychain Access and Retina display support.

Comment: @am1 could make your answer community wiki, please?

Comment: @Loïc Wolff I make it.

Comment: Firefox and Mac OS X just don't mix :( Safari also has add-ons :)

Comment: Some things still put Firefox above competition: intelligent (learning) address bar autocomplete; huge selection of *good* add-ons (Safari or Chrome don't even come close). Too bad Firefox is slower than Chrome...

Comment: Firefox is sssllllooowww.

Comment: @Jonik Yes, the intelligent awesome bar is excellent. I switched to Chrome and really miss being able to type in some arbitrary parts of the URL in order to find a page in my history.

Comment: I hate Firefox UI on Mac. I can't explain why, toolbar and shades and colors feel very, very wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan. Ditto!

Comment: Still my favorite developer tools of all browsers.

Comment: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_TXJcM3hUhjs/S7ApfoG3xHI/AAAAAAAAJPE/f5j_hhXiD-k/s1600/browses-and-transportation-10548-1269487647-48.jpg (look top left)

Answer (score 61):

### [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/)

The only diagramming application worth using.

Comment: I can't say enough good things about OmniGraffle.

Comment: @khedron: Disagreed. It's the easiest diagramming application that I use. I *can* use Illustrator to draw diagrams, but OmniGraffle decreases the amount of time I need to do this, *and* has minimal quality loss.

Comment: @JFW: I think there was a parsing problem somewhere -- I think OmniGraffle is fantastic.  Maybe do a search on "can't say enough good things" to see how I was using this?

Comment: I tried using it for UML stuff and found it really lacking and difficult to use

Comment: @willcodejava: Can you explain more where you found it lacking?

Comment: @Josk K - Sure. I used it straight out of the box. It seemed really clumsy the way you had to choose the right class type, one was just for name, different one for operations, and then one with name, operations and attributes. The connections were also little lines that you had to manually select with the boxes and very difficult to attach correctly.

Comment: Sorry, "can't say any good things" about OmniGraffle.

Answer (score 54):

### [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/)

Yet another virtual machine product. I have tried **Parallels** and am using **VirtualBox** on and off, but VMware's Fusion is what I find to be most efficient and feature-full. **Unity** view is quite efficient when you want to run something side-by-side, while full screen or windowed modes are good for when you need a focus or are just testing out something.

Comment: VMWare Fusion is great! I can share my VMs with VMWare Player for Windows and Fusion can even boot my Bootcamp installation as a VM.

Comment: Fusion's strength is definitely compatibility with it's bigger siblings (ie, Server-class).  I can play around with an appliance, configure and demo it, then migrate the image straight to our server fabric if it fits our usage patterns.  Amazing for small companies or departments.

Comment: Fantastic app...

Answer (score 53):

### [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/)

iTerm2 is a full featured terminal emulation program written for OS X using Cocoa. We are aiming at providing users with best command line experience under OS X. The letter i represents a native apple look and feel of the program interface, and an emphasis on complete international support.

Note: iTerm2 is based on the old iTerm and is supported by the original author.

Comment: Cut is just select text

Comment: iTerm 2 kicks it's ass (not from the same developer)

Comment: Little to slow for me. Look forward to future releases.

Answer (score 50):

### [Reeder for Mac](http://reederapp.com/mac/)

[image: Reeder]

A *gorgeous* RSS reader based on the iOS app.

- Syncs with [Google Reader](http://reader.google.com)
- Can manage Google Reader subscriptions
- Has full [Readability](http://readability.com) integration
- Supports multi-touch gestures
- Switches between reader and webpage view in a swipe
- Has customizable interface and shortcuts
- Supports Lion fullscreen mode
- Offers quick access to services (including Twitter, Readability, Instapaper, ReadItLater and Evernote)

[image: Reeder for Mac]

Answer (score 49):

### [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com)

Sequel Pro is a fast, easy-to-use Mac database management application for working with MySQL databases.

Sequel Pro gives you direct access to your MySQL databases on local and remote servers.

Whether you are a Mac Web Developer, Programmer or Software Developer your workflow will be streamlined with a native Mac OS X application!

Comment: I never liked the app :( I installed http://www.phpmyadmin.net and use it from localhost.

Comment: +1 I think this app is awesome. Much better than the MySQL GUI Tools. Prefer it over phpMyAdmin any day.

Answer (score 47):

### [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/)

Task management tool with an that UI strikes a nice balance between simplicity and functionality. Can be synced with iPhone and iPad versions.

It's a commercial app, and not even very cheap (40€ / $53 currently), but I've come to rely on it a lot.

Comment: One thing Things is desperately missing is proper cloud sync. (Current wifi sync is kinda ok, but it doesn't let you use Things on many computers, for example.) Cultured Code says [it's in the works](http://culturedcode.com/status/), but then they've said that for 1-2 years and nothing seems to be happening. :/ I've used Things for a long time and I like it a lot, but lack of this feature, and of [communication](http://culturedcode.com/things/blog/), makes me consider switching to Evernote or something.

Comment: Evernote *looks like* such a good alternative, but it doesn't seem to have specific To Do functions and the iPhone version is a bit Fisher Price. Things does exactly what it says it does, reliably and professionally, but cloud sync is waaaaay overdue.

Comment: @JBRW: Agreed. Now that I've started using Evernote too, I'd say it's great, but not really a Things replacement for me.

Comment: I love things but switched to omnifocus for its syncing features

Comment: Evernote is not geared for task management.  I love Things interface, but I will like it much more when cloud sync finally debuts this fall.

Comment: I'd be a lot more interested in things if it were not 50 freaking dollars. Considering what it contains, I think it's enormously over priced. $10 would be a no-brainer. $20, and I'd probably still buy it.

Answer (score 46):

### [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=1722)

Take your Magic Mouse and add some more magic to it. Lets you do tons more gestures than OS X alone.

Works for the new trackpad and the multitouch trackpads in laptops too. It's still a bit buggy, but really, really cool.

Comment: Technically just a utility, but I love it so much.

Comment: It would be awesome if not so buggy and heavy.

Comment: It has improved over the last six months or so.

Answer (score 45):

### [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2009/)

-- TeXLive distribution and assorted goodies for the Mac.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. I originally switched to a Mac because of TeXShop and LaTeXit!

Answer (score 44):

## [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-2-public-alpha)

Sublime Text has grown to become my favorite GUI code editor. It feels like a spiritual successor to TextMate (even allowing support for some TextMate bundles like snippets and themes), and has many original+natural features like fully independent text cursors, a very nice search feature, and a rapidly-growing plugin API and surrounding community.

I liked it so much I wrote an [inline lint](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1515&p=6888#p6888) plugin.

[image]

Comment: If I could upvote this ten times. The most awesome, the most underrated editor. Actually it's the first code editor I fell in love with on Mac. I also suggest checking out [Will Bond's page of Sublime Text 2 plugins](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/).

Comment: I also would like to upvote multiple times, this is a fantastic piece of software. Finally I get the power of VIM without the clunk!

Answer (score 41):

### [Skitch](http://skitch.com/)

Skitch allows you to take screenshots on your Mac, edit them and share them with others. It makes the sharing process seamless by making it a natural workflow to send the image (with edited arrows and other highlights helpful to your client) to them via email or automatic website uploads. It is especially popular with the designer community, as they show their clients rough drafts of their work in a nearly automated process. It makes it simple to work remotely with someone and pass on work revisions and get feedback quickly. Other uses include:

- Snap a website
- Capture a chat moment
- Screenshot an application
- iSight snap your bad hair day
- Quickly sketch an idea
- Tap into your iPhoto Library
- Re-open images from your Skitch History

Comment: I use Jing for that as it can be used for screencasts up to 5 minutes as well and not only pics :)

Comment: Skitch is the reason I switched from Windows to Mac over a year ago (although I continue to be unsure if I'm happy about the switch or not.)

Answer (score 40):

### [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/)

Coda is the only web-language-text-editor I like. It does everything you really need for web applications. It remember some common part of code in clips that you can load just by typing their tag name, it completes your html tags, it shows you the list of functions with related variables and autocomplete, it has the powerful Transmit ftp engine built in, it has a great visual CSS editor, it allows you to personalize the text colors and it has HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP doumentation maulaus available from within the application.

Never seen all these features in just one application!

From the developer's website:

> So, we code web sites by hand. And one day, it hit us: our web workflow was wonky. We’d have our text editor open, with Transmit open to save files to the server. We’d be previewing in Safari, adjusting SQL in a Terminal, using a CSS editor and reading references on the web. “This could be easier,” we declared. “And much cooler.”

[image: Screen Capture]

Comment: Looks awesome - you should maybe mention that it costs $100.

Comment: Is it like Kod? I liked Kod...

Comment: I use this 8 hours a day, everyday. Essential

Comment: [Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) totally mops the floor with every other text editor.

Answer (score 39):

### [LaunchBar](http://obdev.at/products/launchbar)

> LaunchBar is a smart and powerful, keyboard driven productivity utility that lets you access and control every aspect of your digital life. Whatever you want to get done on your Mac – with LaunchBar it’s only a few keystrokes away.

Indespensible as a keyboard utility to launch applications, open websites, search the web and a million other things.

Comment: It's also a great clipboard manager, giving access to history via a keystroke. One of the most feature-rich apps I've used.

Comment: Just like quicksilver .)

Comment: I've become a total LaunchBar convert. It's well-supported (unlike Quicksilver) and does things that Alfred does not. I quite literally have an extra 30-60 minutes available every day due to LaunchBar.

Answer (score 38):

### [F.lux](http://www.stereopsis.com/flux/)

f.lux makes your computer screen look like the room you're in, all the time. When the sun sets, it makes your computer look like your indoor lights. In the morning, it makes things look like sunlight again.

Tell f.lux what kind of lighting you have, and where you live. Then forget about it. F.lux will do the rest, automatically.

Comment: It's cool and all, but what's the point?

Answer (score 38):

### [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/)

Improves the finder by adding a tabbed view, as well as other less interesting features. I didn't realize how addicted to this I was until I got a new Mac and couldn't figure out why I couldn't open another finder tab. :-)

Comment: Now supporting CUT-Paste for files! :)

Comment: The only thing missing is more shortcuts like a shortcut to move files around in the dual pane mode

Comment: It's worth noting that you can use it indefinitely for free. The only difference between paid and free is a little banner on the title-bar, and the warm fuzzies you get from supporting a great project.

Comment: @FakeName how is this possible? They mention 14-days-trial?

Comment: @hhh - When the "trial" expires, the only change is a little banner at the top of every window saying "unregistered".

Comment: XtraFinder does almost the same and is free

Comment: I would rather pay money for things that I rely on and work well, in order to ensure they don't disappear in the future.

Answer (score 38):

### [CloudApp](http://www.getcloudapp.com/)

---

[image]

What a **fantastic little App**... it makes easy to **share allmost any file instantly** and when you create a screenshot it automatically uploads it to the web and you have the short URL ready to be pasted anywhere.

a simple Cmd + SHIFT + 4 and ... Paste the url :)

...and you have RainDrops to share other content as photos from iPhoto directly and more

[image]

Answer (score 38):

### [**TextWrangler**](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/)

TextWrangler is the (free) powerful general purpose text editor, and Unix and server administrator’s tool. It is a powerful and richly featured tool for composing, modifying, and transforming text stored in plain-text files.

Among other things, it can open files from (and save them) to remote FTP and SFTP servers, offers a powerful grep engine, supports multi-byte and non-Roman text files, can perform Find Differences on pairs of files or folders, and can be invoked from the Unix command line.

Comment: +1 if you don't want to fork over the cash for BBEdit, TextWrangler is a fantastic alternative, with all of the basic (yet extremely powerful) text editing tools you'll need.

Comment: I use it everyday for any text edit on the go.

Answer (score 37):

### [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/itunes.html)

quote from Thilo:

> I absolutely hate this app, but at the
> same time I (or rather my iPods)
> cannot live without it.
>
> Please, Steve, make iTunes optional
> for iPods and iPads.

Comment: I actually really like iTunes in Mac OSX. The Windows version, not so much; but Mediamonkey (a Windows-only app) can manage music on iPods and iPads, and multiple Linux apps can also manage them.

Comment: I agree that iTunes is a ***** and I hate like most people the fact that we have no other choice. But that's still a great syncing tool for music and backuping devices. I doubt any alternatives offer that features for free.

Comment: Maybe Apple will transition the iOS App Store into the App Store app on Lion, and open up the APIs for backup/sync so developers can make third party replacements for iTunes! But probably not.

Comment: My love/hate for iTunes is that it tries to do everything in one app. (What does organizing apps on your iPhone have to do with "Tunes"?)

Comment: Now you don't need iTunes for a lot of things (OTA updates, Setup, etc.)

Answer (score 35):

### [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/)

Displays customizable system monitoring information like CPU, memory and network usage and hardware temperatures in the menu bar. So like *MenuMeters* but a bit nicer in my opinion.

[image: iStat Menus 3 by Bjango]

Comment: Personally, I like the widget (iStat Pro) that the developers create a bit better.  Free and unobtrusive! :)  http://www.islayer.com/apps/istatpro/

Comment: Just couldn't live without this. A quick and simple way to see my CPU usage, memory usage, etc. etc.

Answer (score 33):

### [Notational Velocity](http://notational.net/)

is an application that stores and retrieves notes.

It is an attempt to loosen the mental blockages to recording information and to scrape away the tartar of convention that handicaps its retrieval. The solution is by nature nonconformist.

Comment: could make your answer community wiki, please?

Comment: +1, and I'll add nvALT, a fork of Notational Velocity that adds support for Markdown, Textile and MultiMarkdown in Preview and a bunch more: http://brettterpstra.com/project/nvalt/

Comment: I'll second the usefulness of this app with Simplenote syncing, especially the fork which Matthew Frederick lists above. :)

Comment: I quit using Evernote and transitioned completely to NVAlt. It's totally killer.

Answer (score 33):

### [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/)

Hands down the best plain-text editor I've ever used.

Comment: Probably also the most expensive.

Comment: You get what you pay for.

Comment: I prefer KomodoEdit. Free and better than BBEdit. I used BBEdit for maybe ten years and swore by it, but then I started using Komodo and never looked back.

Comment: BBEdit is great for web development, but not so great for development in non-web languages.  (Case in point: syntax highlighting.)

Comment: @titaniumdecoy say what? it has built-in syntax highlighting for *dozens* of languages. Down in the bottom left of every window, there's a thing that says "(none)". click that to show a popup menu of all the built-in languages. you can add even more via plugins. i've been using it for bash and ruby scripting all week, and the syntax highlighting has been just fine.

Comment: The last version I used was BBEdit 8.5 (maybe it's changed in version 9) but in my experience there are only 3 syntax highlights for non-HTML languages: keywords, text, and numbers.

Comment: It doesn't suck.

Comment: @ShermPendley, and it supports ponies since version 9.

Answer (score 33):

### [Sparrow](http://www.sparrowmailapp.com/)

Sparrow's hallmark is a simplified user interface reminiscent of Twitter clients such as Tweetie or iOS apps, as opposed to a more traditional e-mail style such as Apple's Mail or Mozilla Thunderbird.

Sparrow currently supports all IMAP email accounts. It also includes features such as **drag-and-drop attachments**, **Growl** support, and **keyboard shortcuts**, as well as **threaded replies** and easy switching between Gmail accounts.

Comment: Sparrow has replaced Mailplane for me, for one reason: super-fast account switching. The UI is ok. Still needs some usability polish.

Comment: POP accounts have been added too.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work behind a proxy with non-default ports...

Answer (score 32):

### [Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/default.mspx)

Office for Mac 2011 is the best option for Mac users who share documents at home, work, or at school.
It comes packed with powerful features for creating artful documents, dynamic spreadsheets, and effective presentations. Plus it’s compatible. You can be confident that your documents will open correctly on Mac or PC.

Comment: @pablo if you really can't live without it, maybe you should put more time in specifying why, no?

Comment: I think iWork pwns :)

Comment: +1 just because I don't get the down votes. I don't particularly enjoy using MS Office, but there are some things it does really well when you get MS Office documents from others. If you're an academic, a lawyer, a project manager, or a sales person, it is a pretty useful piece of software.

Comment: academics use TeX (pronounced 'tech' please! :D)

Comment: +1 because even though I think Office as a whole is an absolute beast of bloatware, Excel has a place in a lot of my processes. Numbers tries a little *too* hard to be different, I think.

Comment: @Carmine That's quite an assumption you make there. I'm an academic and enjoy using TeX myself, but the majority of my colleagues are very uncomfortable with it, both in concept and in practice.

Comment: @Carmine, comparing \TeX to Word is not fair to either.

Comment: @Daniel, probably my view are biased since I come from Computer Science, but I rarely saw papers that didn't look like they were written using TeX. In my department it's recommended for every academic writing.

Comment: I prefer online solutions. My office problems are simple.

Answer (score 32):

### [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/eu/products/desktop/)

Gives almost(!) seamless Windows OS and apps integration.

Comment: This application has saved me several times while taking college courses.  Apparently the college I attend thinks Microsoft products are the only products available.

Comment: I can't believe this hasn't been voted higher.

Comment: Although I’m a VMware and Parallels user, Parallels has the tendency to charge you 49€/year for the “50% faster” newer versions. At the rate Parallels has advertised the speed increase, the virtualized version should be faster than native these days…

Comment: Parallels is much better than vmware. Bought both, only using vmware when I need to share vms with windows users.

Answer (score 30):

### [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/)

- PDF reader and note-taker.

Comment: It's a great application to present slides in PDF format. Preview.app always has this irritating overlay you can't disable.

Comment: Great for annotating PDFs. Notes, highlights, underlines, even freehand drawings.

Comment: The highlighting and annotation features make me prefer Skim even to iBooks.

Answer (score 29):

### [Spotify](http://www.spotify.com/)

For listening to music off the internet. This definitely has become one of the pieces of software I would first install (on a Mac or any other computer).

Note: Spotify is available only in some countries; currently:
Australia, Austria, Belgium, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, the Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, the United Kingdom, and the United States.
The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotify) has [details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotify#Geographic_availability).

Comment: :( Unfortunately not available outside of European countries.

Comment: @JFW: Yeah. Wikipedia notes, however, that according to the company, "Spotify will be launched in the United States before the end of 2010"

Comment: Yeah, the spotify launch in the US has been just months away for over a year...

Comment: It is now available in the US. And it's easy to create a fake account.

Answer (score 29):

### [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/)

Clone, synchronize, backup.

CCC 3 features an interface designed to make the cloning and backup procedure very intuitive. In addition to general backup, CCC can also clone one hard drive to another, copying every single block or file to create an exact replica of your source hard drive. CCC's block-level copy offers the absolute fastest performance and highest fidelity in the industry!

Comment: Can't believe this one wasn't mentioned already.  This is indispensable to me with all the crap I put my Macs through :)

Comment: Yep, this is an app of the highest quality. Another 'must have'.

Answer (score 27):

### [Acorn](http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/)

I have Photoshop, but Acorn is an amazing, lightweight and cheap alternative I go to way, way more often.

Answer (score 26):

### [TotalTerminal (formerly Visor)](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/)

- "A system-wide terminal on a hot-key."  I press ctrl-T (the hot key I chose), and a tab-able terminal window slides down from the top of my screen.  This invaluable for anyone who, like me, is constantly between the terminal and other apps.

This great little tool was originally by Blacktree, who made Quicksilver.

Comment: I keep going for Visor to Window and have now stuck with Visor. Great App.

Comment: I've since switched to http://www.iterm2.com/ which has visor-styel functionality built-in.

Comment: Note: its now called TotalTerminal -- you may want to update the name/link.

Comment: Updated.  Note that this is a community wiki- you can edit it too.

Comment: As a side note, this functionality is built into iTerm2, which I now use in favor of TotalTerminal.

Answer (score 26):

### [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus/)

OmniFocus is designed to quickly capture your thoughts and allow you to store, manage, and process them into actionable to-do items. Perfect for the Getting Things Done® system, but flexible enough for any task management style, OmniFocus helps you work smarter by giving you powerful tools for staying on top of all the things you need to do.

Answer (score 26):

### [µTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/)

One of the best light weight BitTorrent clients.

Comment: Vuze is better :)

Comment: transmission is better :)

Comment: @calavera rather than better I’d say transmission is lighter (by far) ;) (note: I use transmission)

Comment: why is transmission so much better?

Comment: @Richard Transmission was build with being lightweight as a goal.

Comment: I used to use it exclusively but it has become slow to start slow to download torrents. Not sure about better but Vuze is faster which makes it "better".

Answer (score 25):

### [Hyperdock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.de/)

Brilliant.

HyperDock adds long awaited features to your Dock: Select single application windows just by moving the mouse on a dock item, use mouse clicks to quickly open new windows and many more.
[image]

Control iTunes. Hover the mouse over the iTunes dock item to view information about the current song, You can pause or skip songs and even adjust volume just by scrolling on the itunes icon.
[image]

And many more...

Comment: This will be really great when the iron out the bugs.

Comment: This is such an integrated part of my daily workflow. The previews are just eye candy. The shortcuts on dock items, and the resizing of windows are slick and extremely efficient.

Comment: this is one application I actually bought, because it is incredibly handy

Answer (score 24):

### [Cinch](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/)

I **literally couldn't stand to use the Mac without this software**. When I want to full screen an app I just drag the app's title bar to the menu bar and it *"cinches"* itself to full screen. A *must have* for Mac.

Edit: Cinch also allows making a window fill the left/right/upper/lower half of your screen (similar to Windows Snap). Very useful for copy-pasting and comparing.

[image: Screenshot of Cinch Preferences]
[image: Screenshot of Cinch About]

Comment: +1, it's a very useful utility. Though my iMac 27" is so big that I rarely use it :-)

Comment: As an aside, bettertouchtool now has the same functionality, so if you're using both you can save a little bit of resources.

Comment: I actually got used to not have everything maximized, unlike when I was a maximizor freak on windows, once I started using OSX. but nice app! :P

Comment: You can always click <Shift> + maximize button (green button) and you'll get the same functionality. For free...

Comment: @CarlosZ Thank you! I knew there was a way to do it but I forgot. But I'm like @Cawas at this point: I rarely maximize anymore after switching from Windows (where it seems like everyone maximizes).

Comment: Yeah I'm the same @styfle but it is still useful sometimes

Comment: Maybe useful to mention that SizeUp (also suggested as a separate answer) is its supplementary application from the same developer that provides keyboard shortcuts to do the same.

Comment: @CarlosZ - Sorry but <Shift> + green button doesn't do the same. Many apps maximum in the vertical dimension but not in the horizontal dimension. Thankfully Apple has *(mostly)* fixed it with *"Full Screen Apps"* but even it doesn't get it 100% right IMO, so I will continue to use my Cinch.

Comment: Actually BetterTouchTool does this...for free!

Comment: I used to use Cinch, but I switched to Moom for greater functionality and customization.

Comment: divvy is also a good option

Answer (score 24):

### [Daisy Disk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com/)

DaisyDisk scans your disks and presents their content as interactive maps where you can easily spot unusually large files and remove them to get more free space. The map gives you an overview of your data, so you always know what your hard disks are filled with.

Answer (score 23):

### [Eclipse IDE](http://eclipse.org) (free)

Awesome, open source, well-featured IDE primarily for Java, but also supports C++, PHP, and Python, among others. Also has a wealth of third-party plugins.

Comment: Why downvoted? If you *can* live without Eclipse, perhaps just abstain from upvoting this?

Comment: Maybe they hate Eclipse as much as me.

Comment: Amazing for some (not for me).

Comment: Blech. I bailed out of Eclipse in favor of TextMate in my last project.

Comment: Yeah, definitely not a fan. Very un-Mac-like.

Comment: Eclipse has always sucked. I used it since first version. There are so much better alternatives. Look at intellij for java, you will regret the time you wasted on eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse is a fine example of a product designed by committee. It tries to do everything, only to fail miserably at all of them.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with @edgerunner. In my opinion, the UI is horrible, and it's too bulky on workstations with smaller screens. Aside from that, you honestly can't compare it with other apps since there aren't many IDE's to compare it with in the first place. For those who develop PHP applications, Eclipse PDT + Xdebug is heaven-sent. Oh and TextMate is a text editor, not an IDE :)

Comment: Well, for windows migrants like me, Eclipse feels like being at home. I agree that it's UI is not at par with mac, but still I use it for my android development.

Answer (score 23):

### [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/)

GUI Subversion client. From their website:

> Versions provides a pleasant way to
> work with Subversion on your Mac.
> Whether you're a hardcore Subversion
> user or new to version control
> systems, Versions will help streamline
> your workflow.

I will say up front that it doesn't inherently support all of Subversion's features, but it does make managing source code and important document for solo developers and small groups much, much easier than dealing with the command line. It's one of the three apps that gets opened with my "AM" script.

Comment: I like it for browsing the repository (logs, blame, etc).  I tend to use the command line for commits & updates, though.  Faster & easier.  Maybe some day they'll implement my request to search through the "blame" window or display more than one line in logs...

Comment: I like cornerstone better.

Answer (score 23):

### [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)

> calibre is a free and open source
> e-book library management application
> developed by users of e-books for
> users of e-books. It has a cornucopia
> of features divided into the following
> main categories:
>
> - Library Management
> - E-book conversion
> - Syncing to e-book reader devices
> - Downloading news from the web and converting it into e-book form
> - Comprehensive e-book viewer
> - Content server for online access to your book collection

Comment: If you have an ebook reader, this app is pretty much essential.

Answer (score 23):

### [Lastpass](http://lastpass.com/)

Yet another password manager (actually, probably the first one online, I believe prior to 1pass) that integrates well with every browser (well, at least Safari, Chrome and Firefox). You have even an option to use yubikeys with it. I use it for long time and it's just amazing. It does everything I would expect and little more. It monitors when you change password, have a KB of websites and really gets almost all of them, while allow you to configure whenever field with login and password you want. And it's multiplatform.

Back in 2010 it bought Xmarks and must integrate with that as well.

It's completely free to use but it does offer a premium subscription for extra (and unnecessary) features. I personally paid for it as a donation, since I really never use the features.

Comment: I like LastPass a lot, I just wish it had a more polished UI like 1Password.

Comment: 1Password's UI is slow and clunky, but I can't argue with the app's effectiveness. Didn't Lastpass recently have a security breach? I prefer 1Password as it leaves me in control of my password file with Dropbox.

Comment: @Bryson Nope, no security breach. Lastpass recently had a supsect of anomalous behavior on their network and they took preventive measures about it. Nobody ever complained on losing anything stored on lastpass as far as I know, and that measure was very well seem and documented on the web. Just look for it. You can't arguee with this app's effectiveness, UI or service, but I can arguee against a lack of offering backup from my point of view - which reminds me of *Crashplan vs Carbonite*, the later being the pop-pretty one, but the former being the rock-solid-actually-much-better solution.

Comment: I've used last pass for more than a year now, and I still like it. I never thought of trying any other password manager like 1password. I do not need to ;)

Answer (score 22):

### [iChat](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/ichat.html)

I know a lot of people use Adium, and I did too for a long time. But iChat just does what I want and does it slightly more elegantly, so I switched.

I personally can't live without:

- audio and Video calls;
- it can stay in the menu bar without launching the application, and log in at startup (if you are familiar with UNIX, it's like a *daemon mode*);
- support for Jabber.

I also use it for MSN via a [Jabber transport](http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/internet-howto/using-multiple-im-protocols-with-ichat/), which basically lets me connect to MSN through a jabber [server](http://www.jabberes.org/servers/), integrating the two seamlessly. Since there are a lot of [transport-enabled servers](http://www.jabberes.org/servers/) – for ICQ and AIM (which, by the way, are also supported natively in iChat), IRC, Gadu-Gadu, QQ and of course MSN – [you can benefit from iChat's simple interface with whatever IM service you use](http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/internet-howto/using-multiple-im-protocols-with-ichat/).

Answer (score 22):

### [Divvy](http://www.mizage.com/divvy/)

Application for moving and resizing windows using a "grid" approach.

Answer (score 21):

### [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/)

It's small and powerful tool for remove/ uninstalling your applications on OS X.

I use it frequently, it even helps you to remove Cache created the the application from your Mac.

Comment: What a great tool! I didn't know it...

Comment: Link os broken, use http://freemacsoft.net instead.

Comment: def. +1 for mentioning AppCleaner. It's really a great app

Answer (score 20):

### [Colloquy](http://colloquy.info/)

Excellent IRC client that is open source.

Answer (score 20):

## Activity Monitor

A task manager, a utility for performing different tasks to a computer processes, in the Mac OS X operating system. Some of its functions include:

- Quitting or "killing" a computer process
- Viewing the computer's CPU
  load
- Checking the amount of random access memory in use or swapped
  out
- Checking the amount of hard disk read-ins and write-outs
- Checking
  the capacity of storage devices
- Monitoring the computer's network
  usage
- Inspecting running computer processes
- Viewing a process
  identifier number
- Viewing information about a particular process

Answer (score 19):

### [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/)

Simply the best. Save keystroke even if you just use it to write your email address.

Comment: anyone know of a Free or Open Source alternative to textexpander?

Answer (score 19):

### [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/)

Allows you to set keyboard shortcuts for moving windows to certain halves and quarters of the desktop, as well as between desktops when using multiple monitors.

Answer (score 18):

### [Jumpcut](http://jumpcut.sourceforge.net/)

**Minimalist Clipboard Buffering for OS X**

Jumpcut is an application that provides "clipboard buffering" — that is, access to text that you've cut or copied, even if you've subsequently cut or copied something else. The goal of Jumpcut's interface is to provide quick, natural, intuitive access to your clipboard's history.

Comment: As a programmer I cannot live without this!

Comment: Seriously, this is the first app I install on any fresh system, it's that useful. A 'must have' app.

Comment: I used to use the clipboard in QuickSilver but that was unstable. Jumpcut is very stable but it only stores the text, not the formatting.

Answer (score 18):

### [NetNewsWire](http://netnewswireapp.com/)

Easy-to-use RSS reader that syncs with Google Reader (but it doesn't have to). I think my favorite part is that the UI can be completely and logically navigated with the arrow keys even the action of opening a feed entry in your default browser.

Comment: I prefer Helvetireader (with fluid), but I think both will be trumped by the upcoming Reeder for Mac...

Answer (score 18):

### [Path Finder](http://cocoatech.com/pathfinder/)

Path Finder = Finder + Automatic viewer + Shell + Screen Capture + Almost everything you need

Comment: Really great tool!

Answer (score 18):

### [Twitter](http://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/twitter/id409789998?mt=12)

The best Twitter client there is. In perfect sync with the web app itself.

Answer (score 17):

### [Air Video Server](http://www.inmethod.com/air-video/) (Free)

[image: Air Video Server screenshot]

Associate to an iPhone, iPod Touch or iPad, through their [2.99 App](http://itunes.apple.com/app/air-video-watch-your-videos/id306550020?mt=8) this is the best solution to see all your downloaded movies in your devices.

There is a Windows version as well.

---

**Added**

Since iOS 4.3, iTunes Home Sharing is now available for all iDevices, and there is no need of having Air Video, though, you wil need to import all your movies into iTunes in order to be accessible cross network.

For me, I will still stick with Air Video for a long time :o)

Comment: I think that through Home Sharing, you may only stream iTunes compatible videos. So Air Video Server is still needed for all other video formats!

Comment: This app doesn't seem to be available in my country, Denmark.

Comment: @neoneye Im in Denmark and I can assure you that is available as I use it every day. Just click in the link in my answer or throughout their website.

Answer (score 17):

### [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/thunderbird/)

On the whole, still the best email app I know for any platform.

Comment: Thunderbird works great with imap to my gmail account. Microsoft Entourage is somewhat buggy with imap and crashes all the time. Apple Mail is incredibly slow with imap. Thankfully there is Thunderbird. Besides Thunderbird has plugins similar to Firefox.

Comment: Thunderbird is not without its quirks, but I like it better than Mac Mail.

Comment: Lion's new Mail.app now beats the pants off Thunderbird, IMO.

Comment: -1 cannot see a reason to use Thunderbird over the Mail.app. At least in Ubuntu, Evolution beated Thunderbird 1-10. Now in OS X, Mail.app is very good, enough simple.

Answer (score 17):

### [gfxCardStatus](http://codykrieger.com/gfxCardStatus/)

gfxCardStatus is an open-source menu bar application that keeps track of which graphics card your dual-GPU MacBook Pro is using at any given time, and allows you to switch between them on demand. (free, donationware)

---

If you have a dual-GPU MBP, you absolutely **NEED** this program! Did you know that some common applications such as Skype enable your high-powered Nvidia graphics card the entire time they're running? I use it to force my MBP to switch to the power-saving Intel graphics chip when I'm on battery. It adds an extra hour or so of battery life which would otherwise be wasted just because I keep Skype online for chatting.

Comment: this is absolutely essential for me

Answer (score 17):

## [Little Snitch - Firewall](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html)

- **rule** based traffic filtering
- connection alert for undefined rules
- **network monitor**

also see: [Hands Off!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/36086/13414)

[image]

Answer (score 16):

### [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/)

- emacs on the Mac.

Comment: Not just emacs, but emacs that feels like a Mac app -- at least, as much as you want it to.  (Very configurable.)

Comment: May be good if you're a mac user trying to become an emacs user, but not good if you're an emacs user new to a mac. Use native Emacs built for mac instead.

Comment: @Doug - I agree, Cocoa Emacs is a much better way to go. Even if you're a Emacs noob, you shouldn't really get a non-emacs Emacs, it defeats the purpose of learning a cross platform editor.

Comment: -1 on Anti-Aquamacs sentiment.  I use Emacs on 3 platforms and when I'm on my Mac it's always Aquamacs.  I had to undo some of  Aquamacs attempts to fit in the MacOS world ( mainly WRT system keyboard shortcuts ). After that small tweak, it works just like Emacs on my other OSes.

Answer (score 16):

### [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)

No matter what OS, Filezilla had been everywhere I go, and when you start to use it, you can never really get rid off it.

The interface is simple and intuitive, with bookmarks, tree sync, multiple connections on tabs, etc.

Comment: I use FZ too and I like it. I have experienced that Cyberduck and Transmit is having difficulties uploading lots of files via FTP. Then I found Filezilla which has uploaded everything I have thrown at it.

Comment: Transmit wins by a long shot regarding UI, but Filezilla works every time :)

Comment: Filezilla is a lifesaver for quick and easy FTP

Answer (score 16):

### [MacFuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/)

MacFUSE allows you to extend Mac OS X's native file handling capabilities via 3rd-party file systems. It is used as a software building block by dozens of products.

Comment: Awesome when combined with MacFusion.

Comment: yep, MacFusion is must have.

Comment: `This project is no longer being maintained.`

Answer (score 16):

### [DTerm](http://www.decimus.net/dterm.php)

A terminal window for every application. Press a hotkey (I have mine set to Cmd-Opt-Space), and a floating command line pops up over your current window, initialized to the current directory of that window.

Another hotkey allows you to easily paste the name of your current document or Finder selection.

Comment: DTerm does not require SIMBL like Visor does. It's great.

Comment: Also note that DTerm is now in the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 16):

### [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/)

I have a hard time using a Mac without it these days.  How does anyone -- especially a programmer -- work without having the pulse of their Mac at their fingertips?  How else do you tell when your browser is stuck or is really downloading something, if you can't see the network traffic?  When the computer pauses, and you want to know if it's working, just look at the menu to see that the CPU gauges are pegged at 100% -- and much of that is in the kernel.  At a glance, I can instantly see that memory consumption has rocketed up, and with a click I can see that I'm heavily into swap space.  It's just so useful.

Answer (score 15):

### [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/)

(MAMP = Mac Apache MySQL PHP)

Apache Webserver, MySQL Database and PHP in one Package. Easy installation and easy to use for local development of Websites/Webapps.

Comment: Both Apache and PHP are preinstalled with Mac OS, and installing MySQL is a double-click away.

Answer (score 14):

### [Movist](http://code.google.com/p/movist/)

The best movie player for Mac OS X based on QuickTime & FFmpeg. Opens all types of video files and loads quicker than any other app for movies I've ever used.

Features I like:

- file support - plays amazingly well .mkv not to mention all the rest
- simple and minimal UI
- excellent keyboard shortcuts support
- switch from FFmpeg to Quicktime playback with a single click

Comment: praise spaghetti monster... finally an alternative to that pile of un-userfriendly crapola that is vlc!

Comment: Really nice one. Can even play rmvb files !

Comment: Been playing with this a lot and I really love it.  I was beginning to think that I would be stuck with the cruel joke that is VLC forever.  This app beats the crap out of VLC for ease of use.  It even seems less buggy.  I can play the same file in both apps and VLC skips and does all kinds of weird crap while Movist just plays the file perfectly.

Comment: There's a lot of nice features... Shortcuts for seeking a custom number of seconds backward and forward. Restore playback position after closing. Open directly in full screen. Play over the desktop background. Slider for playback speed (no shortcuts though).

Answer (score 14):

### [Garageband](http://www.apple.com/garageband)

This program is, in some ways, the embarrassing bastard child of the audio world. It's an underpowered, feature-crippled version of Logic, one of the best-regarded multitracking applications in the recording world.

Nonetheless, Gagareband is very powerful, and does what I need it to do. While I'd appreciate more flexibility (tempo matching would be nice, and the ability to change time signatures within a project), and the program doesn't handle multiple layers of effects as well as I'd like, it performs brilliantly at what it does do, and it's insanely easy to learn.

Garageband is one of the main reasons <strike>I haven't ditched my G5 Mac for a Windows or Linux machine</strike> I took so long to replace my G5 mac. (Now I use GB *and* Logic on a Macbook Pro.)

Comment: Go Garageband! I love using it!

Answer (score 14):

## [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html)

I'm amazed it hasn't been mentioned as an answer already.  It's saved my data on more than one occasion from catastrophic hard drive failure.

From its website: SuperDuper is the wildly acclaimed program that makes recovery painless, because it makes creating a fully bootable backup painless. Its incredibly clear, friendly interface is understandable, easy to use, and SuperDuper's built-in scheduler makes it trivial to back up automatically. It's the perfect complement to Time Machine under Leopard and Snow Leopard, allowing you to store a bootable backup alongside your Time Machine volume—and it runs beautifully on both Intel and Power PC Macs!

Comment: I've been using this for many years now and it has saved my stuff on several occasions, plus it's great for when you upgrade that harddrive on your Mac. It's being updated whenever needed (and no more than that, which is also great).

Comment: One big drawback: the machine muse already be awake for scheduled backups to occur.

Answer (score 13):

### [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/mac/)

Picasa is free photo editing software from Google that makes your pictures look great.

Comment: I wished they had Picasa Viewer inbuilt like windows version.

Answer (score 13):

### [MPlayer OSX Extended](http://mplayerosx.sttz.ch/)

It is a media player. I like it more than VLC player.

Comment: I like both, but I'm using mplayer more nowadays. It is great!

Comment: I tend to go with VLC or QuickTime Player with Perian in this case, I find MPlayer to be too buggy.

Comment: For the last year, I moved from VLC to MPlayer X without regret. I like its interface a lot more than VLC's. I also have Perian installed for when I use Quicklook or play a video in Finder (the play button in the file icon).

Answer (score 13):

### [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)

A free software, cross-platform digital audio editor and recording application (from Wikipedia).

If you want to record plain old audio onto your computer, Audacity is a pretty easy way to do it.

(Apple's optical drives from the past several years have implemented [region lockout DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_code) in firmware, rather than simply software, so I can't play back DVDs from multiple regions on my Mac.  It's a laptop, so "just buy a second DVD drive" isn't really feasible, and I'm not brave enough to try flashing it with a third-party firmware.  Plugging in my DVD player to my Mac is quick and easy, though!)

Comment: My it's ugly! I hate to see cross-platform software on Mac. Of course it does “the job” but I find applications like this degrading the whole experience.

Answer (score 12):

### [Xee](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/xee.html)

*Xee is a lightweight, fast and convenient image viewer and browser. It is designed to be a serious tool for image viewing and management, with a sleek and powerful interface. Xee is useful as a more powerful replacement for Preview, or most any other image viewer available on Mac OS X.*

Comment: Xee's fullscreen mode is much better than Previews.

Answer (score 12):

## **[Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/index.php)**

OnyX is a (free) multifunction utility for Mac OS X which allows you to verify the Startup Disk and the structure of its System files, to run misc tasks of system maintenance, to configure some hidden parameters of the Finder, Dock, QuickTime, Safari, Mail, iTunes, Login window, Spotlight and many Apple’s applications, to delete caches, to remove a certain number of files and folders that may become cumbersome and more.

I've seen this utility majorly improve the performance of Mac OS X.  I run it about once a month to automate maintenance scripts and it's helped identify problems like the need to repair a disk several times.  A very useful and effective tool.

Comment: For the most part, these types of utilities actually SLOW system performance (cache files are a good thing, they're designed to store the result of repetitive actions so the same actions don't have to done over and over again). I'd advise only using OnyX is a troubleshooting utility for fixing glitches

Answer (score 12):

#### [nvALT](http://brettterpstra.com/project/nvalt/)

Unbeatable note-taking app, featuring online syncing with the plain text notes web service, Simplenote, and the simplenote apps for iPhone and iPad.

nvAlt is a fork of the existing application, [Notational Velocity](http://notational.net/).

Answer (score 12):

### [Fantastical](http://flexibits.com/fantastical)

Amazing background app for quickly accessing and adding events to your mac's calendar.  Supports Caldev Sync to keep your mac's calendar always up to date, as well as natural writing event creation.

Bring up fantastical with a keyboard shortcut, and then type out your new event.  Hit return and it's in.  Quickly view all the upcoming events for the next month and beyond.  Next time you open iCal, all of your data will remain intact as Fantastical works with your software in the background.

Answer (score 11):

### [**Shift It**](http://code.google.com/p/shiftit/)

(Uses the same principles as [**SizeUp**](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/), but free)

This application will let you resize and move your windows without having to using a mouse. Here are some of things you can do with Shift It:

- Shift the focused window to left/right/top/bottom half of the screen.
- Resize the focused window to fill the whole screen.
- Move the focused window to the center of the screen.

Shift It is a great tool that lets you organize your windows. Now you can read documents side-by-side without having the pain of manually resizing the windows.

Answer (score 11):

### [cdto](http://code.google.com/p/cdto/)

> Fast mini application that opens a Terminal.app window cd'd to the front most finder window. This app is designed (including it's icon) to placed in the finder window's toolbar.

Comment: This is a great little app, though I don't think it's been updated to Lion, yet.

Answer (score 11):

### [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/)

Augments the Open Folder and Save Folder dialogs from any application to allow you to immediately jump to any folder currently open by Finder. (Also works for folders open with Path Finder).

Once you start using this app, it's really hard to live without it.

Comment: I used this back in Classic OS 9. There is no point to it that I know anymore, since the standard behavior for Open/Save dialogs is that you can drag any folder or file into them to navigate to that location. If there are other unique benefits, please add info.

Comment: Apple should have bought and integrated this app into the years ago.

Comment: I don't see the point off this application

Answer (score 11):

### [Gitbox](http://www.gitboxapp.com/)

Gitbox is a Git repository manager.

Answer (score 11):

### [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/)

Play any audio across your network to a whole host of devices, all in sync! Airfoil sends audio to remote speakers including iOS devices, other computers, and hardware devices like the Apple TV and AirPort Express. Airfoil for Mac gives you any audio, everywhere.

Basically, what previously only iTunes could do (send audio to an AirPort Express) you can now do with all applications.

Answer (score 11):

### [Geektool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/)

Geektool allows you to put a tail of your syslog on the desktop, or the output of some command, or some graphic/chart/picture.

It's a bit like a more single-minded Dashboard for your desktop. You can make awesome clocks, or beautiful server monitoring, or just a fortune cookie (if you install fortune with HomeBrew).

It's not perfect (it would need sticky borders, continuous command output and sane multi-monitor behavior for that) but it's a lot of fun, using little resources.

Comment: Geektool is awesome, but I do have to say that it does eat up memory. :-(

Comment: @daviesgeek — How so? I've got it running 25 scripts currently for a total of 18.9 MB. In 1998 that would have been considered eating memory, but not today.

Comment: @ioi Hmm... It may just be the PPC computer I was running it on. :-)

Answer (score 10):

### [Tunnelblick](http://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/)

> Tunnelblick is a free, open source Graphic User Interface (GUI) for [OpenVPN](http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html) on Mac OS X. It provides easy control of OpenVPN client and/or server connections.

Answer (score 9):

### [Notify](http://www.notifyapp.com)

Notify is an awesome email notifier for Mac OS X. It fits seamlessly into your menubar, only vying for your attention when you have new mail. Notify supports mutliple accounts, including Gmail, MobileMe, and Rackspace Email.

Answer (score 9):

### [Echofon](http://www.echofon.com/)

A really simple, intuitive twitter client.  This is the one that got me to switch from Tweetie.

Comment: Great because if you use it on your iPhone or iPad it will also sync read tweets in your timeline.

Answer (score 9):

### [X Lossless Decoder](http://tmkk.pv.land.to/xld/index_e.html)

X Lossless Decoder(XLD) is a tool for Mac OS X that is able to decode/convert/play various 'lossless' audio files. Supported audio files can be split into tracks with a cue sheet when decoding. It works on Mac OS X 10.3 and later.

XLD is Universal Binary, so it runs natively on both Intel Macs and PPC Macs.

Comment: I use this pretty much constantly for archiving my CD collection to lossless FLAC and then later into mp3.  It's better than EAC (Windows only) in my opinion.  Easier to set up, faster, and far less buggy.

Answer (score 9):

### [Unrar](http://download.cnet.com/unRAR/3000-2072_4-26159.html)

This is a command line utility to unpack the **.rar** files on Mac OSX. You can't unpack the .rar files natively on OSX, where this small util is useful.

Comment: "The Unarchiver" does this in the GUI and can be set as your default so it acts like the native OS X archive utility.

Answer (score 9):

### [Aperture](http://www.apple.com/aperture/)

Aperture is a fine app for photo management and editing for professionals and advanced amateur photographers alike.
It supports many file-formats and raw image file formats.

For a complete feature list see the link above.

One of my favorite features is having a full screen view while still having image control for editing via a HUD.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

### [Isolator](http://willmore.eu/software/isolator/)

> Isolator is a small menu bar
> application that helps you
> concentrate. When you're working on a
> document, and don't want to be
> distracted, turn on Isolator. It will
> cover up your desktop and all the
> icons on it, as well as the windows of
> all your other applications, so you
> can concentrate on the task in hand.

It's a small utility, but one that I find pretty indispensable. One of the first apps I install on new Mac.

Comment: I try to keep my desktop empty so then I can achieve the same with Cmd-Shift-H to Hide Others and Cmd-Shift-D to hide the Dock. Fullscreen in Lion really helps too.

Comment: I mean Cmd-Option... Sigh

Answer (score 8):

### [A Better Finder Rename](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/)

A Better Finder Rename has long been the file renamer of choice for tens of thousands of professionals, businesses and hobbyists across the world.

[image]

Comment: No offense anyone, but I do find it somewhat strange and hilarious that in the Mac world there are commercial applications for something as trivial as *renaming files* (or [deleting them](http://superuser.com/questions/10676/permanently-deleting-files-on-mac-os))...

Comment: Windows have programs too for mass renaming. A free alternative to A Better Finder Rename is the program: NameChanger, it's not that advanced, but it's something.

Comment: @Jonik: it's not about simple rename, but mass rename of many files :-) On Windows I use built-in tool in Total Commander for this.

Comment: @Peter: Of course it's about mass rename; I still find it odd and funny, especially the price tag. (NB: my background is in the Unix world, where powerful command-line has always existed and people generally are adept at it, which might partly explain my reaction :-)

Comment: I'd prefer to do these things in Terminal. Also Automator is really helpful!

Comment: @fardjad - +1 for using the Terminal / Automator.

Comment: @neoneye Got a link for NameChanger?

Comment: @CyberSkull here is a link to NameChanger http://www.mrrsoftware.com/MRRSoftware/NameChanger.html

Comment: I use Easy Rename for it's simple find and replace kinda UI

Answer (score 8):

### [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com)

If I need to choose only one software to install on my Mac, I would install *Mathematica* by Wolfram.

Comment: This is a great app, and really helped me understand my last Trig class better.

Answer (score 8):

### [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/)

XBMC is an award-winning free and open source (GPL) software media player and entertainment hub for digital media. XBMC is available for Linux, OSX, Windows, and the original Xbox.

Comment: Runs beautifully on a Mac Mini under my TV...

Answer (score 8):

## [iMovie](http://www.apple.com/ilife/imovie/)

iMovie is the best amateur video editing software out there. It has a very small learning curve, which makes it great for doing quick projects. I used iMovie for the longest time, then switched to FCE. I still use it for minor projects.

Answer (score 7):

### [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardDownload)

MusicBrainz is an audio file metadata (or "tag") editor.  It has options for both automatic and manual modification of audio metadata.

It's cross-platform (Linux/Mac OS X/Windows) and written in Python and is the official MusicBrainz tagger.

Picard supports the majority of audio file formats, is capable of using audio fingerprints (PUIDs, similar to other fingerprinting apps like Shazam and SoundHound), performing CD lookups and disc ID submissions, and it has excellent Unicode support. Additionally, there are several plugins available that extend Picard's features.

Comment: You need to give a better explanation of what benefit it gives to users. The only thing you've told them is that it is "cross-platform", not very useful at all.

Answer (score 7):

### [Clean My Mac](http://macpaw.com/)

The world's easiest-to-use maintenance solution. This all-in-one tool includes everything you need to keep your Mac clean and healthy.

Comment: I thought Mac OS X itself had everything I needed to keep my Mac clean and healthy...

Comment: Clean My Mac clears cache files, broken links and also it has an uninstaller to remove applications completely.

Comment: @Josh: Healthy yes, clean, no.

Comment: You don't need this! The use of these types of utilities is hyped by intense advertising, and it's generally a huge scam industry!

Answer (score 7):

### [Opera](http://www.opera.com)

Because it's still my favourite browser. After having used it on Windows for eight years, I took it with me when I "switched" four years ago.

Browsers are always subjective, but I like Opera because I rely on its single-key shortcuts, used its mouse gestures a lot before I moved over to a glass trackpad, I have dozens of tabs open at any time, it has session handling, bookmark syncing, and dozens of other neat, small things. And everything is built in and just works.

I could probably get Firefox to do everything Opera does for me, but it would be a hassle, and it would be even slower than it already is without any extensions. I could never get Safari to do everything I need.

Answer (score 7):

### [NTFS-3G (Tuxera)](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/)

We still need to learn how to play nice with windows systems (and filesystems).  I use this to access my NTFS drives.

NTFS-3G is a stable, read/write NTFS driver for Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenSolaris, QNX, Haiku, and other operating systems. It provides safe handling of the Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows 2000, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7 NTFS file systems. A high-performance driver is available commercially for embedded devices.

Answer (score 7):

## [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com)

A very powerful backup application that allows you to backup to external drives, other computers, and/or their own cloud at a very reasonable price.  It has an impressive compression rate and allows you to create multiple backup sets to backup different data to different locations.  It has a well-designed interface and allows you to specify scheduled or continuous backups.  It offers versioning and 448-bit encryption.  For a home user the software is free to use if you choose not to backup to their cloud.

Comment: TimeMachine not enough?

Answer (score 7):

### [I Love Stars](http://www.potionfactory.com/blog/2008/05/15/i-love-stars)

Displays iTunes’ current song’s rating in your menu bar. Click to change rating. Supports keyboard shortcuts. Has a configurable sound to remind you to rate an unrated song. Disappears when nothing’s playing.

Answer (score 6):

### [Pomodoro](http://pomodoro.ugolandini.com/)

Pomodoro Desktop is a desktop application for Time Management on your Mac OSX. It is a simple but effective way to manage your (coding) time, and it's based on the Pomodoro technique you can find [here](http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/).

Answer (score 6):

### [Air Display](http://avatron.com/apps/air-display/)

Technically this is both an iOS and Mac OS X application.  What it does is let you use your iPad as a second monitor with your Mac.  When I am using my Mac my iPad isn't usually in use (unless a family member stole it) so I use Air Display to make it useful while I am using my Mac.  You get a **1024x768** or **768x1024** display that rotates and flips automatically - like you would expect.

The Mac portion is free, but you buy the iPad App.  Runs with Windows too.  Operates over WiFi, but you can always create a private network if one does not exist or it is too slow!

Comment: Seems interesting (if a bit pricey). Consider adding to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/great-ipad-apps too.

Comment: I finally sprung for it and couldn't be happier. It works *really* well with my Mac and with my WinXP computer. Definitely got my money's worth.

Answer (score 6):

### [OmniDiskSweeper](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidisksweeper/)

OmniDiskSweeper scans your hard drive telling you where your largest files are, making it easy to delete cruft. It's intelligent in how it presents this information hierarchically.

Answer (score 5):

### [VirtualHostX](http://clickontyler.com/virtualhostx/)

For web developers who develop websites locally on their Mac. **VirtualHostX manages your Apache Virtual Hosts** and enable the use of domain names that point to your local machine (even non-routable domain names.) VirtualHostX does this by managing your Mac's `hosts` file and your Apache `httpd.conf` and `httpd-vhosts.conf` config files. It even supports *MAMP* (although I don't use MAMP.)

It's **one of my top 5 favorite apps** and one I'd hate to do without. I use it every time I start a new project!

[image: Screenshot of VirtualHostX]

Comment: I much prefer MAMP.

Comment: @Josh K - Apples and Oranges.

Answer (score 5):

### [iChm](http://www.robinlu.com/blog/ichm)

iChm is an ebook reader for CHM (Microsoft Compiled HTML Help) files.

Answer (score 5):

### [SABnzbd](http://sabnzbd.org/)

SABnzbd is an Open Source Binary Newsreader written in Python.
It's totally free, incredibly easy to use, and works practically everywhere.
SABnzbd makes Usenet as simple and streamlined as possible by automating everything we can. All you have to do is add an .nzb. SABnzbd takes over from there, where it will be automatically downloaded, verified, repaired, extracted and filed away with zero human interaction.

Answer (score 5):

### [KeePassX password vault](http://www.keepassx.org/)

KeePassX is a cross platform secure password saver. Like Keychain, but you can use it on your mobile phone and windows computers.

Comment: you really should consider lastpass. I abandoned my keepassX.

Comment: KeepassX is an ugly non-native app.  Its only redeeming quality is that it is cross-platform.

Comment: 1Password is cross platform as well, and MUCH more popular.

Comment: I use keepassX because it is open source software, vs lastpass, 1password which are not. I'm no fan of the non-native look, but my best alternative - and I would love to be corrected on this - is to use an encrypted textfile

Comment: If you don't need to share a password file with others or open it on other platforms, simply use Keychain Access (comes with OS X). Otherwise KeePassX is still handy.

Answer (score 5):

### [Postbox](http://www.postbox-inc.com/)

> Postbox 2 is first class email software that puts you in the driver’s seat. Stay on task, find information quickly and act, not react.
>
> Unified Account Groups
>
> Focus Pane
>
> Quick Reply

Exist both free and paid versions

Answer (score 5):

### [Kod](http://kodapp.com/)

*a programmers' editor for OS X*

An open source project that is slowly replacing TextMate for me.

Comment: Kod looks interesting, but it is nowhere near powerful enough for me to switch from TM at present.

Comment: Kod is more powerful, just not enough add-on's / plugins. More importantly it's too buggy at the time (v0.0.3). That with the huge development slow-down , it isn't looking good. A lot like TM2 :0

Comment: "slowly" is the word. :) look at macvim/vim for a serious all purpose text editor. I left textmate for it a while ago.

Comment: I better throw cocoa Emacs.app in here for good measure, this or MacVim are where you go when you are finished with toy editors. (Emacs.app is my preference, however I have it heavily customized from the default, and looks a lot like my ideal version of TextMate now.)

Answer (score 5):

### [Papers](http://mekentosj.com/papers/)

Designed for scientists, Papers manages PDFs of journal articles. Articles imported to Papers can easily have their metadata applied from journal databases. Articles can then easily be sorted by author or journal, and labeled with different categories. Papers has an associated iOS app that it syncs with.

Answer (score 5):

### [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/)

SizeUp allows you to quickly position a window to fill exactly half the screen (splitscreen), a quarter of the screen (quadrant), full screen, or centered via the menu bar or configurable system-wide shortcuts (hotkeys). Similar to "tiled windows" functionality available on other operating systems.

Comment: It is Duplicate!

Answer (score 5):

### [Plex Media Center for OS X](http://www.plexapp.com/about.php)

Plex bridges the gap between your Mac and your home theater, doing so with a visually appealing user interface that provides instant access to your media. Plex can play a wide range of video, audio and photo formats as well as online streaming audio and video. The real power of Plex is found in its library features: Organize your media into versatile libraries, automatically retrieve metadata from the Internet, and display your libraries using one of the visually stunning skins.

Plex has all but replaced VLC as my primary media application.

Answer (score 5):

### [Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com/)

A Finder replacement. Two panes file management program. Not as cutomizable as Total Commander but has a lot of features builtin.

Answer (score 5):

### [Shady](http://mattgemmell.com/2009/11/02/shady-for-tired-eyes)

If you're finding your laptop screen too bright at night even on the minimum brightness, Shady's the right guy for you. Basically, it puts a transparent overlay over your entire screen, dimming it anywhere between 0% and 90% of normal.

Answer (score 5):

### [muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com/)

muCommander is a lightweight, cross-platform file manager with a dual-pane interface. It runs on any operating system with Java support (Mac OS X, Windows, Linux, *BSD, Solaris...).

Here's a non-exhaustive list of what you'll find:

- Virtual filesystem with support for local volumes, FTP, SFTP, SMB, NFS, HTTP, Amazon S3, Hadoop HDFS and Bonjour
- Quickly copy, move, rename files, create directories, email files...
- Browse, create and uncompress ZIP, RAR, 7z, TAR, GZip, BZip2, ISO/NRG, AR/Deb and LST archives
- ZIP files can be modified on-the-fly, without having to recompress the whole archive
- Universal bookmarks and credentials manager
- Multiple windows support
- Full keyboard access
- Highly configurable
- Available in 23 languages : American & British English, French, German, Spanish, Czech, Simplified & Traditional Chinese, Polish, Hungarian, Russian, Slovenian, Romanian, Italian, Korean, Brazilian Portuguese, Dutch, Slovak, Japanese, Swedish, Danish, Ukrainian and Arabic.
- Free Software (GPL)

Answer (score 5):

## [Voodoopad](http://flyingmeat.com/voodoopad/)

[image]

> VoodooPad is a place to write down your notes and thoughts. Ideas, images, lists, passwords, your mom's apple pie recipe. Anything you need to keep track of and organize. VoodooPad will grow with you without getting in the way. Drag and drop folders, PDFs, applications, or URLs into VoodooPad, and they will link up just like on the web. And with powerful search, nothing will be lost or out of reach.

Comment: ..........what?

Answer (score 5):

### [Adobe Creative Suite / Master Collection](http://www.adobe.com/products/creativesuite/mastercollection.html)

The absolute **KING** of creative tools. Sure, the price is a bit up there, although there really isn't anything that can touch the versatility of having seventeen applications at your disposal. I've used some of these tools since their very existence (Illustrator, Photoshop) and I honestly can't imagine working without them. It would be difficult to describe what they all do; infinite possibilities.

> Photoshop Extended, Illustrator, InDesign, Acrobat X Pro, Flash
> Professional, Dreamweaver, Fireworks, Contribute, Adobe Premiere Pro,
> After Effects, Audition, OnLocation, Encore, Bridge, Device Central,
> Media Encoder, Media Encoder

◆ I'm a bit shocked this is just now making it's debut here.

Answer (score 5):

### [Audio Hijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/)

Audio Hijack allows you to record any sound from your Mac or input device. You can also mute certain applications. This is my go-to-application for any audio recording.

Comment: I love this app. There are still some regularly scheduled radio shows that this app records for me like an audio TiVo. It will also let you record the streaming radio from an app while ignoring other app or system sounds.

Comment: Yes that's what I use it for!!

Answer (score 5):

### [Stickies](http://www.apple.com/macosx/apps/all.html#stickies)

It's Apple's program for taking notes. Very minimalistic and fast.

Your notes can be:

- formatted how you like
- edited with hyperlinks
- drag and drop pictures
- export as *.txt
- custom color of note

[image: Stickies Icon]

Answer (score 5):

### [Soulver](http://www.acqualia.com/soulver)

An amazing calculator that does it all with a nice text-based interface.

Just type your problem as you'd write it on paper. You see your answer instantly. No setting up formulas, no equals button. If you make a mistake, you don't have to start all over again, you just hit delete.

Answer (score 5):

### [Hiss](http://collect3.com.au/hiss/)

> Hiss is an OSX app that forwards notifications from Growl enabled apps
>   to Notification Center in Mountain Lion.

Currently in beta, but it does an awesome job of piping all your Growl notifications into the Notification Center of OS X Mountain Lion. The only real downside to it is that it flags all notifications with the Growl icon.

Comment: I was just adding this one.

Answer (score 4):

### [InsomniaX](http://semaja2.net/insomniaxinfo)

Disables sleep mode, so you can shut your lid without the system hibernating.

Comment: I think it may be important to mention that this is probably not a good idea for new unibody Macbook Pros since the keyboard is one of the primary ways that cool air is pulled into the laptop (the MBP only has one external vent slit for pushing air out in the back).

Answer (score 4):

### [Google's Quick Search Box](http://code.google.com/p/qsb-mac/)

An application launcher, like Quicksilver. Having tried both, I found Quick Search Box's UI to be cleaner and the overall application to be faster.

Comment: QuickSilver is much more then simply an application launcher. ;)

Answer (score 4):

### [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html)

This handy tool allows you to customize OSX in various ways so that it is more efficient for you uses and allows you to access settings that you normally couldn't

Comment: [Cocktail](http://www.maintain.se/cocktail/index.php) has even more options, but is commercial. Then there's also [Secrets.prefpane](http://secrets.blacktree.com/).

Comment: TinkerTool provides a convenient graphical user interface for scores of customization functions that could only be accessed otherwise with command-line commands and obscure edits of system preference files. Many participants in this forum seem to prefer doing everything from the command line, but for those of us who don't, tools like TinkerTool are extremely valuable. TinkerTool will also show you customization options that you probably did not even know existed.

Comment: Cocktail is not a substitute for TinkerTool. Cocktail's main purpose is to provide system maintenance functions such as clearing caches and repairing permissions. TinkerTool's only purpose is user interface customization. Cocktail has a few user interface customization options, but TinkerTool has many more than Cocktail in that regard.

Comment: I have both Secrets and TinkerTool. TT is great for getting to many hidden system config options and I use Secrets for handling the rest.

Answer (score 4):

### [PCalc](http://www.pcalc.com/)

This is an awesome calculator that I have been using for at least 10 years. For basic arithmetic and quick calculations this app can't be beat.

It is also available from the [Mac App store](http://www.pcalc.com/mac_app_store/pcalc).

Answer (score 4):

### [Fraise](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/fraise/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions_%28FAQ%29)

> Fraise is a free text editor for Mac OS X Leopard 10.6 which is both easy to use and powerful. It is designed to neither confuse newcomers nor disappoint advanced users.

General-purpose text editor with extensive syntax highlighting support. Can be downloaded via [MacUpdate](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33751/fraise).

Comment: This application is no longer developed. The original app, `Smultron`, which was abandonned, is now developed again (and available on the App Store). So Fraise developer said there would be no other update to Fraise.

Answer (score 4):

### [0xED](http://www.suavetech.com/0xed/0xed.html)

a free, native OS X hex editor based on the Cocoa framework.

- Fast editing of large files.
- Unlimited file size (limited by what the actual file system supports).
- Small memory footprint.
- Instant opening of files of any size.
- Resource fork editing.
- Full hex/text search/replace.
- Binary/text Cut/copy/paste support.
- Plug-in system to display your custom data types.

Comment: this is a great hex editor.

Answer (score 4):

### [Nocturne](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-nocturne/)

For all those low-light situations, Nocturne is a tool for inverting colors, changing screen tint etc. So I can make the screen dimmer while keeping it readable, when the dimmest backlight setting is too bright.

I especially like the *Invert hue* option, which can be used to keep colors the same while inverting black/white.

Comment: +1 I actually use this on my on my Mac Mini connected to the TV. Its "Dim when inactive" menu bar feature (coupled with hiding the Dock) gives the appearance of a having nothing on screen but the desktop picture

Comment: I use this to work at night for 1: saving my eyes and 2: if I want to work on my laptop in bed without pissing off my wife!

Answer (score 3):

### **[Overflow](http://stuntsoftware.com/overflow/)**

Overflow is an application designed to quickly launch applications, open documents, or access folders while reducing the number of items needed in your Dock.

Answer (score 3):

### [Base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/)

Base is an awesome tool for managing SQLite databases. It has an intuitive interface and allows you to easily create or alter tables. I especially like that the transcript shows you exactly what queries Base is executing against your database.

Answer (score 3):

### [Clipmenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/)

A simple yet powerful clipboard management tool.

Answer (score 3):

### [JustNotes](http://selfcoded.com/justnotes/)

A simple notes app that syncs with [Simplenote](http://simplenoteapp.com/)--my favorite notes app for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

## [AppFresh](http://metaquark.de/appfresh/)

AppFresh helps you to keep all applications, widgets, preference panes and application plugins installed on your Mac **up to date**.

All from one place, easy to use and fully integrated into Mac OS X. AppFresh works by checking the excellent [osx.iusethis.com](http://osx.iusethis.com/) for new versions and lets you download and install available updates easily.

Answer (score 3):

### [QuickCursor](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/quickcursor)

QuickCursor lets you use your favorite editor to edit text in any Mac app that has a text input field. It's particularly useful for editing textboxes on web pages.

Answer (score 3):

### [AppTrap](http://onnati.net/apptrap/)

When you move a .app to the Trash, AppTrap notices this and offers to remove all associated library and preference files.

Comment: +1. But... Don't blindly "OK"  the "remove" offer and delete good files when upgrading an app!

Answer (score 3):

### [AntiRSI](http://tech.inhelsinki.nl/antirsi/)

A timer that detects when you're using the computer and tells you to take breaks if you've been at it too long. I like it because it has two timers running concurrently, one for small, frequent breaks, the other for long, rarer breaks. It's intelligent, configurable, and can show the timers on the dock icon.

Answer (score 3):

### [TinyUmbrella](http://thefirmwareumbrella.blogspot.com/)

TinyUmbrella is a great app for anyone who has an iOS device they want to downgrade to a previous firmware for one reason or other. It backs up and saves the SHSH blobs or "Keys" required to complete the restore.

Answer (score 3):

### [Bowtie](http://bowtieapp.com/)

Bowtie (free) is a little app for controlling iTunes and Last FM. It comes with several features, and it's really well done. Here's a brief description from its webpage.

> Bowtie is a free application that allows you to control iTunes and your iPhone (requires 99¢ companion app) with customizable shortcuts, submits your songs to Last.fm with support for Loving and Banning, and sports a very simple, yet very powerful, HTML5 + CSS + JavaScript theming system.

It's got some pretty cool "Bowlets", or little controllers/information displayers that can sit on the screen. There are plenty to choose from (these are just a few I have downloaded from the theme browser):

[image: Bowtie Themes]

This is one of my favourite (PaperRift by creeze):

[image: PaperRift bowlet]

Download on [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/bowtie/id404387136?mt=12).

Answer (score 3):

### [Port Map](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/portmap/)

Easily [configure ports](https://superuser.com/questions/30917/how-to-make-a-port-forward-in-mac-os-x/40696#40696), assuming you have a UPnP router.

Answer (score 3):

### [Hex Editor](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/)

Practically every editor, including text editors, lie about the contents of files. Even programming languages change or omit certain characters. In general this is intended to help you see what they think you are looking for, but sometimes you just want to see things how they really are

Note: The original hexeditor I linked to is no longer on offer, so I have updated the link with the suggestion from neoneye

Comment: Hex Fiend has much better keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @neoneye Link for Hex Fiend please?

Comment: Link above is now redirected elsewhere; no "Hex Editor" tool is evident at the destination.  **Hex Fiend**, an open source alternative, can be found at http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/

Comment: You should also look at `0xED` in this list.

Answer (score 3):

### [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/)

A free, open-source Integrated Development Environment for software developers. All the tools needed to create professional desktop, enterprise, web, and mobile applications with the Java platform, as well as with C/C++, PHP, JavaScript and Groovy.

Answer (score 3):

### [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/)

LibreOffice is *the* [FLOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open_source_software) office suite. It's comparable to Microsoft Office while available for free.

Comment: This is basically the better version of OpenOffice.org, forked when [Oracle refused to cooperate with the community](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libreoffice#Initial_release).

Answer (score 3):

## [Boom](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/boom/id415312377?mt=12)

- provides a **system-wide** equalizer
- boost the overall volume of your computer
- boost volume of specific audio files
- fast access via menu icon

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Hands Off! Firewall](http://www.metakine.com/products/handsoff/)

- Prevents applications from phoning home
- Block **outgoing**/incoming network connections
- Block subdomains
- Supports IPv4, IPv6 and local networks
- Block read/write file operations
- **Monitoring network connections and disk access**
- export/import rules
- **default rules** for certain applications (Mail, Safari,...)
- access via menubar

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/)

Moom is a very configurable window management tool. Some useful features include convenient and fast window placement and resizing using grids, saving window layout profiles, configurable hot keys, and much more.

Comment: By far better than ShiftIt and Cinch!

Answer (score 3):

### [Little Ipsum](http://littleipsum.com/)

It’s my favorite dummy text / *lorem ipsum* generator for OS X (free). What it makes so special is the selection mechanism from the menu bar (words… sentences… paragraphs):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## **[Bark](http://barkplug.in/)**

From their site:

```
Who says you can't teach an old dog new tricks? Bark intelligently brings
notifications from Growl into Notification Center under OS X Mountain Lion.
```

Much like [Hiss](http://collect3.com.au/hiss/), Bark forwards your Growl notifications to Notification Center in Mountain Lion. The catch though is it forwards them not as "Growl Notifications", but as notifications from the actual app that sent them, making the experience totally seamless.

Screenshots might make it more clear. I reckon Bowtie and Coda 2 don't support Notification Center natively, but with Bark this is what you get:

[image: Bowtie through Bark]
[image: Coda 2 through Bark]

And on notification center they look like this:

[image: Bowtie / Coda 2 in Notification Center]

Correct icons, correct grouping, the plugin is completely free and works with the newer versions of Growl (App Store versions)... definitely worth checking out!

*PS: Coda 2.0.3 I think now supports Notification Center natively, but you get the idea...*

Answer (score 3):

### [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com)

Secrets is a PrefPane that lets users access hidden settings in many Mac OS X applications. It is also [open source](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-secrets/) and user driven, any user can submit a secret and have it immediately available in the Secrets for anyone to use.

[image: Secrets PrefPane]

Answer (score 2):

### [xGestures](http://alum.hampshire.edu/%7Ebjk02/xGestures/)

- adds mouse gestures to every program.

Answer (score 2):

### [Rulers](http://www.omnidea.it/rulers/)

from the webpage:

> "Rulers" allows you to create rulers
> on the entire screen area like most
> common graphic editors allow on their
> working areas only. The guide lines
> enable you to measure and position
> objects with precision. Rulers is
> incredibly useful in many fields, such
> as computer graphics, desktop
> publishing and web design. Rulers can
> also be used to select a screen area
> and take a screenshot that is
> automatically saved to your desktop or
> copied to system clipboard.

Comment: This is also similar to xScope by IconFactory, with Rulers being comparatively lightweight.

Comment: I prefer xScope, though I hadn't heard about rulers.

Answer (score 2):

### [Rip](http://sbooth.org/Rip/)

Rip is an application for accurate CD audio extraction.

It uses a smart combination of the AccurateRip database and CD Paranoia to ensure that the CD will be ripped accurately through the fastest means available.

Answer (score 2):

### [Spirited Away](http://drikin.com/)

Spirited Away checks each running application's activity, and if an application isn't active for a certain fixed time, Spirited Away hides the application automatically. It is, in effect, Spirited Away :-)

This is a great productivity app, keep your workspace clean and focussed, by hiding all the apps you are not using. No more distractions in the background!

Answer (score 2):

### [Breakaway](http://mutablecode.com/apps/breakaway)

Pull out your headphones, and iTunes pauses. Plug it back in, and it starts again. A simple application that makes your life that much easier.

Answer (score 2):

### [FinderPop](http://www.finderpop.com/)

This tool provides a ton of enhancements to the contextual menu.  It allows you to select move,copy,alias a selected item (icon) to pretty much any folder via pop-up hierarchical folder lists. Built-in preview stuff, and more.

Answer (score 2):

### [Textual: IRC for Mac OS X](http://www.codeux.com/textual/)

> Textual is a lightweight IRC client
>   created specifically for Mac OS X. It
>   was designed with simplicity in mind.
>   Textual has taken the best of IRC and
>   built it into a single client. Its
>   easy-to-use functionality combined
>   with scripting support makes it an
>   ideal IRC client for novice to
>   advanced users.

I tried Colloquy; I tried MacIrssi; I tried [X-Chat Aqua](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xchataqua/); but for a GUI client, I have happily stuck to using Textual.

Answer (score 2):

### [Vox](http://voxapp.didgeroo.com/)

> Vox is a little and simple music player for Mac OS X with support for many file types, including FLAC, MP3, AAC, Musepack, Monkey's Audio, OGG Vorbis, Apple Lossless, AIFF, WAV, IT, MOD, XM, Games Music and many others. Includes numerous effects like Equalizer, Reverb, Time Stretch, Pitch Shift, Echo. Moreover, all supported files can be exported to AAC+, Apple Lossless, WAV and other formats with enabled effects.

This is one truly awesome little app which is sadly not well-known. I'd even say Vox was one of the reasons I switched to Mac. Nothing but the essentials for a music player. Besides, it offers some nice audio features (e. g. resampling with antialiasing) as well as built-in Last.fm integration and nifty controls in menubar.

I prefer to organize my music in folders by artists and albums and not bother with music libraries used in most modern audio players, so Vox's ability to play all files in a folder is the single most important feature to me.

If you feel that iTunes has grown far too big for a music player or just don't like messing with audio libraries you should really give Vox a try.

Answer (score 2):

### [Pianopub](http://dev.kunugiken.com/Pianopub/)

> Pianopub is a free Pandora internet radio player for OS X.
>   It is a port of [Pianobar](http://github.com/PromyLOPh/pianobar), so please support the original developers. 
>   It is for use with your account from the Pandora.com internet radio service.

By far the best Pandora client ever — in form of a native Mac OS X app.

Answer (score 2):

### [The Hit List](http://www.potionfactory.com/thehitlist/)

THL is a to-do list/GTD organizer that supports tagging, contexts, tabs, unlimited nesting, alarms, cloud syncing, keyboard shortcuts, and a ton of other features. It's a *great* piece of software, and comes from a developer with impeccable attention to detail. There's a companion iPhone app as well.

Answer (score 2):

### [Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/) by Mozilla Labs

Prism allows you to turn **any** webpage into an application. I've used this numerous times.

Comment: Better app is Fluid.

Comment: @TheWellington Fluid is pretty cool! I've never even heard of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### [Readiris](http://www.irislink.com/c2-1584-189/Readiris-12---OCR-Software-------Convert-your-Paper-Documents-into-Editable-Text-.aspx)

OCR software for OS X.

> Readiris 12 family quickly converts your paper documents into editable text or PDF files you can edit, share and store!

Comment: I've tried Readiris many times since maybe version 7, and after many hours and a LOT of money, I hate the program with a passion. Perhaps version 12 is wonderful, but to my mind this is a very un-Mac-like program that not only produces poor results, but also crashes and corrupts itself. The developer cares very little about the Mac, and progress has been slow. I used it because despite this horrid performance, it was the best OCR app available. Luckily I don't do OCR much anymore, and while I hope Readiris has improved, I am a skeptic.

Answer (score 2):

## [Grooveshark](http://www.grooveshark.com)

I know what you are thinking: "This isn't an application!", but wait a second, it actually is! I made Grooveshark into a standalone application with hotkeys. I love it and use it **all** the time! Information about turning Grooveshark into a standalone application [here](http://thegeektechblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-make-grooveshark-stand-alone.html).

Answer (score 2):

### [Sloth](http://sveinbjorn.org/sloth)

Sloth is a graphical frontend for the console tool `lsof`. If don't know what that is, it doesn't matter!

Sloth makes it easy to find out which applications are using which files.

Sloth displays a list of all open files and sockets in use by all the applications your user account is running on the system. This list is presented along with the names of applications using the file and their process IDs.  Includes support for regex list filtering, process killing, sorting and more.

Answer (score 2):

### [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/)

> ControlPlane supports multiple contexts where a context is defined as
>   a location or activity you are performing.  Using evidence sources you
>   can create a set of rules that tell ControlPlane what context to apply
>   to your environment.  When ControlPlane enters or leaves a context a
>   set of Actions are performed.

In other words: it will turn off screen saver protection when You arrive home and turn it back when You leave. And so much more.

Answer (score 2):

### [CheatSheet](http://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/)

Just hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd> a bit longer to get a list of all active short cuts of the current application. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

### [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/)

> With ScreenFlow you can record the contents of your entire monitor
>   while also capturing your video camera, microphone and your computer
>   audio. The easy-to-use editing interface lets you creatively edit your
>   video, and add additional images, text, music and transitions for a
>   truly professional-looking video. The finished result is a QuickTime
>   or Windows Media movie, ready for publishing to your Web site or blog
>   or directly to YouTube or Vimeo.

Answer (score 2):

### [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) & [Co.](http://www.jetbrains.com/products.html)

These are the best IDEs for Web development I found so far. The features go way beyond what simple editors offer. Intellisense, refactorings, debugging, source control integration are my favorite.

Answer (score 2):

### [XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/)

XtraFinder add Tabs and features to Mac Finder.

• Tabs.

• Dual Panel & Dual Window.

• Cut & Paste.

• Colorful icons in Sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

### [VideoMonkey](http://videomonkey.org)

This is an open source replacement for VisualHub. It's free and lets you do all kinds of mass video conversions as well as auto-tagging your video with tv show / movie metadata.

Comment: videomonkey.org didn't resolve for me.  I did find their sourceforge page however: http://videomonkey.sourceforge.net/Video_Monkey/News/News.html

Answer (score 1):

### [Hyperspaces](https://hyperspacesapp.com)

Set names and separate background pictures for different spaces.  Really helps me focus on one specific project at a time and helps me avoid tangents.

Answer (score 1):

### [Clyppan](http://www.omh.cc/clyppan/)

This is a really good clipboard manager.

Answer (score 1):

### [Zooom/2](http://coderage-software.com/zooom/)

Zooom/2 is a Mac desktop utility that redefines how you can resize, move and align your application windows - making you faster and more productive.

On many X-based desktops (such as KDE and Gnome) you can resize windows from any side, move windows by clicking anywhere on the window, and switch windows simply by pointing your mouse. Zooom/2 brings the same functionality to Mac, and I can no longer live without it. For example, in my configuration I hold Shift-⌘ and click anywhere in a window to move it. No more hunting for the menu bar or the resize corner!

Comment: It also supports using fn as a modifier and snapping windows to screen edges and other elements.

Answer (score 1):

### [Minuteur](http://www.phg-home.com/index_mac.html)

Quick and easy to use timer. It's programmable, so you can do (10+2)*5 or the Pomodoro technique on repeating intervals.

The App is localized into English, but the linked webpage is French. The [MacUpdate](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/19356/minuteur) page is in English.

Answer (score 1):

### [Warp](http://www.ksuther.com/warp/)

From the website:

> Warp is a preference pane that allows you to use the mouse to switch between Spaces rather than using the keyboard.
>
> Warp offers the ability to display a live preview of a space when you move the mouse to the edge of the screen, allowing you to see what you have on another space before actually switching to it. Clicking the preview will then warp you to that space.

Answer (score 1):

### [Alarms](http://www.mediaatelier.com/Alarms/)

> Alarms app is the reminder system you never knew your Mac was missing. Just drag the items you want to be reminded of to the Alarms menu and place them on the time line.

Answer (score 1):

### [Pow](http://pow.cx)

> Pow is a zero-config Rack server for Mac OS X. Have it serving your apps locally in under a minute.

Simple to use and indispensable if you are doing any kind of Rails/Sinatra/Rack development

Answer (score 1):

[Final Cut Express,](http://www.apple.com/support/finalcutexpress/) a discontinued video-editing software made by [Apple.](http://www.apple.com) Final Cut Express is one step above [iMovie,](http://www.apple.com/ilife/imovie/) with up to 99 video tracks, 99 audio tracks, and 12 compositing modes. My favorite features of FCE are [Chroma Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key), Color Correction, and [Livetype](http://www.apple.com/support/livetype/), which comes with Final Cut Express.

Answer (score 1):

### [DragThing](http://www.dragthing.com/english/about.html)

is a utility that provides an alternative to the Dock. It is tremendously flexible and customizable in letting you design your own way to organize application launchers.

Let me be frank; I've been using a Mac every day since 1987. I cannot live without DragThing because I could never get used to using the Dock, which appeared with the first Mac OS X circa 2000 (and I was using developer builds of Mac OS X before the first version went public). While you can configure DragThing to perform many functions, what I use it for is to provide an application menu and an application launcher that behave the same way they did in Apple Macintosh System 7 through Mac OS 9. That's the way I want it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Final Cut Express](http://www.apple.com/support/finalcutexpress/)

I am so amazed no one has mentioned this!
The best video editor for the price. Unfortunately Apple has abandoned FCE to go on to FCPX. I couldn't live without FCE!

Answer (score 1):

### [SecondBar](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=79)

SecondBar adds a second menu bar to your secondary monitor. Although there are a few bugs, it's a great little application.

Answer (score 1):

### [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)

An indispensable macro tool. Trigger a macro based on a hotkey (overriding the frontmost app if appropriate), typed strings (a la TextExpander, the status of an app, the system waking or your logging in, at certain times or dates, etc.

A macro can do pretty much anything you can do manually -- manage apps, choose menu items, click on windows or dialog boxes or whatever, display text or Growl or other notifications, etc. -- including running scripts. Macros can also include flow control (if, while, etc.) for less straightforward tasks (e.g. in Photoshop <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> deletes the current layer if a layer is selected or the current group of layers if a group is selected).

One great use is unifying commands across apps, e.g. have <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> zoom out and <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> zoom in for every app that supports the concept rather than having to remember how, say, OmniGraffle does it vs Photoshop vs Numbers.

> Keyboard Maestro enables you to create or record custom macro shortcuts that you can activate at any time. For example, your macros could help you navigate runnings applications or work with an unlimited number of clipboards. Best of all, every macro you create is available using simple keystrokes you choose.

Answer (score 1):

## [Growl Extras - Hardware Growler, Growl Mail,...](http://growl.info/extras.php)

#### [HardwareGrowler](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hardwaregrowler/id475260933?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)

Find out when a hardware status changes on the Mac.

#### [Growl Mail](http://growl.info/growlmail/)

Notifications for incoming mail.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/)

MarcoPolo brings context-aware computing to your Mac! It allows your computer to determine its context through gathering evidence from your environment (evidence sources), using flexible rule-based fuzzy matching to make an educated guess (rules), and then performing arbitrary actions upon changing context (actions).

I use MarcoPolo to run scripts (actions) when I arrive at work, as determined by WiFi hotspots detected or IP addresses assigned (context).

Comment: Seems like ControlPlane (see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/41826/19225) is the "new" MarcoPolo:

_ControlPlane creating using code from version 2.5.1 of the MarcoPolo project still available at http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/.  Development of MarcoPolo seems to have come to a halt and ControlPlane attempts to pick up where MarcoPolo left off.  As of version 1.0.0, ControlPlane is 64bit and fixes the WiFi Evidence Source._

Answer (score 1):

## [teleport](http://abyssoft.com/software/teleport/)

Okay, did a search of all eight pages posted to date, and didn't see "teleport" listed.

This little free System Preference gets installed on two computers, and then you can move your cursor off the screen of one, onto the screen of the other.

I run a dedicated Mac Mini server, but my main computer is a Mac Pro. I have the server screen above the pro screen, and I can simply move my cursor up to the server, like you'd do with multiple monitors on the same computer. BRILLIANT!

This is so much simpler and easier than using Screen Sharing or other such tools.

It also copies the clipboard of one computer to the other. This can cause a significant delay if you have something huge on the clipboard.

Comment: Why not using Synergy+ ?

Answer (score 1):

### [Simple Comic](http://dancingtortoise.com/simplecomic/)

> Simple Comic is the most intuitive comic reader on the Mac. Its clean interface gives you full control of your viewing experience without getting in the way. Reading comics on a computer has never been easier.

A great program for looking any any set of archived images.

[Simple Comic viewer window http://dancingtortoise.com/simplecomic/images/screens/two_page.png](http://dancingtortoise.com/simplecomic/images/screens/two_page.png)

Answer (score 1):

### [Yep](http://ironicsoftware.com/yep/index.html)

- I scan all my documents to PDF and use Yep to track & find them.
- No filing! Everything goes to a single target folder, Yep takes care of it.
- Tag documents
- Automatically finds all PDF, iWorks, Office, et.al. documents anywhere on your hard drive.
- Does not use a database like some similar apps. So I can access documents via finder; move, copy, delete, etc. easily.
- In conjunction with a [Fujitsu Scan Snap scanner](http://www.fujitsu.com/us/services/computing/peripherals/scanners/scansnap/scansnap-s1500m.html) Yep is a dream to use.

Answer (score 1):

### [Tweetbot for Mac](http://tapbots.com/tweetbot_mac/)

Though relatively new. Tweetbot for Mac is bringing the same innovation to the Mac platform that it's had established on iOS for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

### [EVE](http://hotkeyeve.github.com/eve/)

From website:

> EVE helps you to learn shortcuts, in order to increase your productivity with MAC OS X. Every time you execute an action using the mouse, EVE will show you the matching shortcut.

Great application! I use it with [Cheatsheet](http://cheatsheetapp.com/Landing/).

Answer (score 1):

### [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/)

SparkleShare allows you to create your own DropBox. In this way you don't have to pay for more space, if you have your own server, and you don't have to share data with no one else (service provided) except the people you decide.

**How does it work?**

> SparkleShare creates a special folder on your computer in which
>   projects are kept. All projects are automatically synced to their
>   respective hosts (you can have multiple projects connected to
>   different hosts) and to your team's SparkleShare folders when someone
>   adds, removes or edits a file.

**Why SparkleShare?**

> The idea of SparkleShare sprouted at the GNOME Usability Hackfest in
>   London, where a couple of designers came to the conclusion that they
>   didn't have a good (Open Source) collaboration tool to share their
>   work (for more background, read “The one where the designers ask for a
>   pony”). They didn't like how the good collaboration tools were
>   proprietary, and that using them meant having to give up privacy,
>   control and other rights. What they needed was something that they
>   could run and control themselves, without having to depend on other
>   companies.

Answer (score 1):

### [Vienna](http://www.vienna-rss.org)

Viennna is a free open source RSS/Atom reader. Very flexible and version 3 will have Google Reader support.

[image: Vienna main window]

Answer (score 1):

### [Glui](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/glui/id601359958?mt=12)

I never really enjoyed using Skitch, even before Evernote bought them. Not too long ago I heard about Glui and have fallen in love ever since.

It's quick, provides some useful annotating tools, uploads to Dropbox and the automatically copies the share url to your clipboard.

Really has improved my workflow as a programmer. Makes it super easy to share screens when working with others.

Answer (score 1):

### [Monosnap](https://monosnap.com/)

Monosnap is a free screenshot program for Mac OS X and Windows. The program allows users to create screenshots, annotate them and upload them to the cloud.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### [Hub List](http://hublistapp.com/)

Very promising successor of The Hit List.

Description:

A HTML5 compliant productivity application

From the author:

> Hub List tries to strike a balance between simplicity and
>   customization. If you’ve every managed a software project then you’ve
>   probably spent more time then you care to admit inside an ugly bug
>   tracking application that a bunch of developers convinced you would
>   make them more productive. You probably use another app to manage your
>   business projects and then something else to help you remember all
>   those pesky personal todos like getting your mom a card for mother’s
>   day. Rather than try to replace all those tools Hub List strives to
>   provide real-time two-way integration with all of them so you can be
>   more productive using the tools you already have.

Website:

[hublistapp.com](http://hublistapp.com/)

Comment: Spiritual successor or actual successor? It seems like it was inspired by THL, not coded by the same guy.

Comment: You should add some description of what Hub List does.

Comment: Hub List is basically a clone of THL written because some people were unhappy with THL's development schedule. THL is now released in version 1.0 with a companion iPhone app and cloud syncing. Hub list will likely die off.

Comment: That URL is no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

### [switchDiskSizeBase](http://web.me.com/brkirch/brkirchs_Software/Mac_OS_X_Software.html)

*In Mac OS 10.6 disk and file sizes are measured in base 10 (one kilobyte is defined as 1000 bytes, one megabyte is defined as 1000 kilobytes, etc.) in Finder and Disk Utility.  Unfortunately this has created a lot of inconsistency even when working with Apple’s own programs since most of them still define file sizes in binary units (one kilobyte is defined as 1024 bytes, one megabyte is defined as 1024 kilobytes, etc.).  This utility will switch the measurement of disk and file sizes in both Finder and Disk Utility back to binary units (or if the measurement has already been switched to binary units it will restore the system back to using base 10 units).*

After the switch in Snow Leopard I never could get used to read file sizes in Finder with base-10. This application patches the Foundation framework in order to get back base-2 units. I can now again compare disk space and file sizes with other operating systems or output from shell tools.

Answer (score 0):

### [Podworks](http://www.scifihifi.com/podworks/)

I recently referred to the app in [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/new-harddrive-cannot-sync-my-ipad). If you own both a Mac and an iPhone or iPod, this application is a must-have.

Podworks works around iTunes to allow transfer of media to/from Mac and iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

### [iMote](http://www.mkdsoftware.com/imote/)

I use it mostly to rate songs and get Growl to display the currently playing song. From the website:

> iMote is a simple, elegant, and lightweight program for controlling iTunes from just about any application. Play/pause, change tracks, select playlists, adjust volume, rate tracks, and more using fully customizable hot-keys or a universal menu bar item. iMote includes a beautiful iPod-esque floating window, indicating current track information, and Growl support if you want an even more streamlined experience with your other Growl-enabled applications. Written using Cocoa, iMote is lean and mean, consuming minimal system memory and CPU time. iMote is the original iTunes controller.

Answer (score 0):

### [News Anchor](http://newsanchormac.com)

One of the few RSS readers that *doesn't try* to imitate an e-mail application, News Anchor converts inanimate text in news feeds into lively television-like news broadcasts. With News Anchor you can now "read" news feeds while eating or doing other things.

[image: News Anchor Screenshot]

Comment: Whoa. I really think I **could** *live without* this application. :-D though the read out loud option may be useful to someone.

Comment: They could do without the ugly anchor animation.

Answer (score 0):

### [Vuze](http://vuze.com/)

*Vuze, the most powerful bittorrent app on earth*

Comment: And the heaviest.

Comment: When they moved away from being just a BitTorrent client I dropped it. A Java-based media application and torrent client? My computer is crushed under the weight of it.

Answer (score 0):

### [Monocle](http://wafflesoftware.net/monocle/)

A great utility to make a web search (Google, Wikipedia, any other search engine) just a keystroke away regardless of what application I'm in.

Answer (score 0):

## [Livetype](http://www.apple.com/support/livetype/)

Livetype is an awesome title generator that came with FCE. It does have a rather steep learning curve if you aren't used to keyframing, but it generates professional-looking titles at a great price.

Answer (score 0):

## [Spark](http://www.shadowlab.org/Software/spark.php)

> Spark is a powerful, and easy Shortcuts manager. With Spark you can create Hot Keys to launch applications and documents, execute AppleScript, control iTunes, and more...
> You can also export and import your Hot Keys library, or save it in HTML format to print it.
> Spark is free, so use it without moderation!

I use this all the time and love it!

Answer (score 0):

### **[App bar](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/app-bar/id464303501?mt=12)**

App Bar displays a quick list of all your applications. This is the quickest way possible to find and open any application launched from your Status Bar or Dock. All apps are listed alphabetical and the scroll list is well laid out and always just a click away.

Answer (score 0):

## [JiTouch](http://www.jitouch.com/)

JiTouch is similar to BetterTouchTool, but with many, many more options. The one thing it doesn't have is Windows 7 snapping, so keep BetterTouchTool around for that. I would highly recommend this application, though it's a paid application.

Answer (score 0):

## [Shimo - VPN management for the Mac](http://www.chungwasoft.com/shimo/)

Receive notifications via Growl. Assign network locations and wireless networks to profiles.

- CiscoVPN Support
- OpenVPN Support
- IPSec Support
- PPTP/L2TP Support
- Hamachi Support
- SSH Support
- Use Keychain for Passwords
- Certificate Management
- Advanced Notifications
- Automatic (Re-)Connection
- Syncing Profiles with MobileMe
- Scriptable with AppleScript
- Global Keyboard Shortcuts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Sophos Anti-Virus Mac Home Edition](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-mac-home-edition.aspx)

**Free** commercial AV software.

- **Fast signature updates**
- **Low cpu usage**
- **Live scan**
- Define custom scan scopes
- Define action upon treat alert (log only, cleanup, move threat, delete threat)

[image]

Comment: Sophos anti-virus (like all other anti-virus) ONLY scans for windows malware (to avoid accidental contamination of networked PCs)

Answer (score 0):

### [Scrawl](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scrawl/id480126603?ls=1&mt=12)

Scrawl is nifty little note taking app for the Mac that I made with iCloud support.

Answer (score 0):

## [iProcrastinate](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iprocrastinate/id413662017?mt=12)

iProcrastinate is the ideal task manager for anyone who doesn't want their todo list to get in the way of actually getting things done! Great for anyone who is looking for a mobile, easy-to-use task manager. (Not just for students!) Add birthdays, soccer practice and conference calls, all without missing a beat.

Uses iCloud to sync between Mac and iOS. Couldn't do my homework without it.

Answer (score 0):

### [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/)

From JetBrains, the makers of IntelliJ. Has a *lot* more refactoring support than XCode and a more powerful editor. Especially useful to anyone coming to iOS development from the Java world.

Answer (score 0):

### [Emacs 24](http://emacsformacosx.com)

Best text editor ever...Supports VIM bindings plus has org-mode and can run a shell, edit directories, view images, etc. Make sure to use the built-in package manager to load add-ons. Solarized-dark is an excellent color scheme.

Comment: Or use Aquamacs for a version pre-customized for OS X. I wouldn't cite VIM bindings as a key feature of Emacs though...

Comment: The vim bindings are evil are awesome after too many years of ctrl-[key] really started to hurt my wrists. I almost went to vim, but then discovered evil.

Answer (score 0):

### [Herald](http://erikhinterbichler.com/software/herald/)

Allow notification plugin for Mail.app. In ML you have notification center, but with Herald you also get the full message body which I really like.

Answer (score 0):

### [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/mac/ccleaner)

One of best cleaning utility.

CCleaner is the no. 1 cleaning utility for Windows PC. In Mac it does the same function, cleaning temp files, cookies, cache etc. for making more space available. The tools section provides utilities to uninstall an application, change startup option, erase free space and manage permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you add a little more information about CCleaner? What exactly does it do?

Comment: I've used this app for almost my entire PC life. Good to have it on Mac too.

Comment: Macs DON'T need this. Temp files, cookies and caches are GOOD (they're invented for a reason) and significantly speed up your system! I'd only even recommend clearing them for troubleshooting issues

Answer (score 0):

### [SafeWallet](http://www.sbsh.net/password-manager-safewallet)

SafeWallet is a very useful and complete password manager, which allows you to safely keep you passwords, credit card pins, notes, and many more stored on your Mac.

It also provides functionality for sharing your wallet with the iOS App (SafeWallet for iPhone). In this way your wallet is always with you and always synced.

Answer (score 0):

## [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) (free/open-source)

This application can **trigger a wide range on actions based on different events**, its mainly use being to start/stop application based on your context.

For example when you bring your laptop to work it can start Outlook. You can detect that you are at work based on the network IP, presence of a wireless network, or many other options.

Answer (score 0):

### [Debookee](http://www.iwaxx.com/debookee)

Debookee is a network traffic analyzer that allows you to see your traffic by protocols: HTTP, HTTPS, TCP, DHCP, DNS, SIP etc ...

It can also scan all the devices present on your network, and intercept the traffic of any of them, perfect to see what your iPhone or tablet is sending over the network.

Answer (score 0):

### [PogoPlug](http://pogoplug.com/software)

There's a software version as well as the hardware box that creates a cloud server. The software version allows me to set a folder or drive on my Mac and link to it so I can let others access. I know there are other ways to do this, but for me the $20 ($30 now, I think) was well spent as the software is simple and no glitches.

If you have a good friend and you both agree to leave your computers running, you can use the other's extra drive to store your backup with no monthly fee, just install a decent size drive at the friend's house.

Answer (score 0):

### [Airmail](http://airmailapp.info)

After last year Sparrow acquisition from Google and development freeze, Airmail is new, actively developed mail client. It does not hide it's Sparrow roots, but exceeds it and new features are constantly added.

Answer (score 0):

### [Entropy](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dentropy/id655858295?mt=12)

[dEntropy Logo http://bit.ly/16BItjE](http://bit.ly/16BItjE)

I use it as my daily productivity booster since it moves all files I haven't touched within the last week from my Desktop into my archive. It has many more features you may find interesting. Here is a [trailer](http://bit.ly/10HImVl).

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the creator. Ask me anything. ;)

Answer (score 0):

### [Unclutter](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/unclutter/id577085396?mt=12)

Main features:

- Instant, configurable access even in full screen mode
- File Storage, to keep your Desktop clean from temporary files
- Notes, your digital notepad
- Clipboard preview, so you always know what you're about to share
- Draggable cards that can stick on top of other windows
- Retina display support

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)

[image: Gimp icon]

Very powerful and free and open source image editor, inspired by PhotoShop. Has layers, RGB and indexed modes, and more tools and filters than you can shake a stick at.

Since version 2.8 Gimp is OS X native.

[Screenshots](http://www.gimp.org/screenshots/) - [Features](http://www.gimp.org/features/)

Answer (score -2):

### [StockMeter](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/business_finance/stockmeter.html)

[image]

Answer (score -3):

### [Fuzzyclock](http://www.objectpark.org/FuzzyClock.html)

"Often you don't need the exact time in hours, minutes and seconds. A more human readable style like "five past ten" makes more sense. For that, you can now use FuzzyClock. FuzzyClock is a menubar clock which displays the current time in a "fuzzy" style." I use the handwriting font. (Alfred, Cloudapp and Growl have been said).

[image: fuzzyclock]