# How do I find my CPU's temperature?

Tags: utilities

There are a number of posts that talk about CPU temperature.  Is there a utility built in to Mac OSX that I can use to determine the current temperature of the CPU?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) @[Mark](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/237/mark) [mentioned](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/how-to-determine-cpu-temperature/9650#9650) are no longer freeware, the [**iStat nano**](https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/status/istatnano.html) and [**iStat Pro**](https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/status/istatpro.html) Dashboard widgets are free.

I personally use iStat nano for my system monitoring needs. Here it is showing the temps it can read on my iMac:

[image: iStat nano temps]

If you [hover over](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441/os-x-dashboard-widgets-you-cant-live-without/8463#8463) the widget, you can change the view. I usually have it running in "[Overview](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441/os-x-dashboard-widgets-you-cant-live-without/8463#8463)" mode, which shows CPU, RAM, HDD*, fan*, temperature*, network* and uptime info.

*) user-configurable, e.g. which temp sensor's readings are displayed

Comment: I would like to update this answer in order to tell the reader that iStat nano and iStat Pro no longer exist, these apps can not be downloaded anymore. How are such edits usually done?

Comment: You can still find them on download sites, google for "iStat Pro download" for example.

Answer (score 2):

I use [smcFanControl](http://www.eidac.de/) which can tell the internal temp of your computer as well control the speed of the fan (in case you need to increase/decrease the speed manually).

Answer (score 1):

There are APIs that code can call. Various utilities have been written touse them. Ones I have used are

[Temperature Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TemperatureMonitor.html) - free - there is also a Dashboard widget
[iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) - which now has to be paid for the old version was free