# New harddrive, cannot sync my iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad

I just got a new hard drive and I want to sync all my iPad stuff back into my iTunes but it's just asking to erase the iPad. I just want all my books and stuff to be back in my iTunes.

Comment: Apple specifically doesn't want you syncing with multiple computers.  To do this, you will need to find an application that will pull the data from your iPad back to your computer.  It may involve jailbreaking your iPad.

Comment: @Harv That is not accurate. While hard drive failure on a computer is not common, iTunes _does_ offer an option to backup your purchases from an iOS device without syncing.

Comment: @mummey Purchases, yes.

Comment: Could you Authorize this new computer and check whether you can bring back those docs. But without using a 3rd party tool, you can't bring back the Music.

Comment: Authorized it, but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I referred to in the comment:

1. Right/(Control)-Click on iOS device in sidebar of iTunes.
2. Select *Transfer Purchases*

This copies over everything you purchased using the iTMS, App store, and iBooks.

For all content you put on the device that you purchased/received elsewhere, the process is a bit more complicated. Here are some suggestions:

- Right/(Control)-Click on iOS device in sidebar of iTunes and select *Backup*. These at least gives you a place you can quickly fall back on.
- If the computer in-question is a Mac, I can't recommend [Podworks](http://www.scifihifi.com/podworks/) enough.
- If Windows... well I haven't tried any, but found [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/147239/is-there-a-good-windows-equivalent-to-podworks) on SuperUser.

Hope this is enough to get you going. Best of luck!

Comment: Great instructions, +1