# Free utilities for a power users switching from Windows to OS X?

Tags: utilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OS X Applications you can't live without](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82/os-x-applications-you-cant-live-without)

I'm looking for usual tools, like messenger, file transfer, text editor and so on.

PS. I would make it community wiki, but I do not see the option?!

Answer (score 0):

[Adium](http://adium.im/) for instant messaging, it also has a nice menu icon. If you used Pidjin on Windows, this is the OS X alternative.

Answer (score 0):

[Weather Bug](http://weather.weatherbug.com/desktop-weather/weatherbug-mac.html) to see temperature on menubar, also direct link to full whether info.

Answer (score 0):

[Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) (commercial) or [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) (free/Donationware) for FTP. Version 4 of Cyberduck is even available for Windows.

Comment: For FTP I do prefer [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php) because it is free and cross-platform.