# Any recommendations for a before&after software installation scanner/uninstaller?

Tags: software-recommendation, macos

I'm trying to decide on an uninstaller that does before and after system scans.

So far, I've come across these three:

1. **CleanApp** (syniumsoftware.com/cleanapp/) - which I saw someone recommend in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/470/how-do-i-uninstall-a-program-completely-on-a-mac/471#471)
2. **Yank** (matterform.com/mac_software/uninstaller/index.html)
3. **Uninstaller** (macmagna.com/)

So I was hoping if anyone on here has any tips or recommendations on these or any others.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All the apps you listed seem to be commercial products while there are some free tools that can do this for you.

Based on [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82/os-x-applications-you-cant-live-without) thread I tried and used [AppCleaner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82/os-x-applications-you-cant-live-without/6603#6603). It seems to do the job well.

Comment: Thanks! I've used that app before but unfortunately without an initial system scan before software installation it doesn't seem to be as thorough as one that takes a before & after snapshot of the system to compare them for differences.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised nobody has mentioned [AppZapper](http://www.appzapper.com/) (which looks great too). You can also opt to use [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) which sits in the background and helps you when you move an application to the trash by giving you the option to also trash its associated preference files etc.

Hazel also does a lot more. For example, I have Hazel monitor my download folder and labels files according to the amount of time that has passed since I downloaded them. After two weeks, it moves the items to a folder for items scheduled for deletion. After an item has been there for another two weeks, they are automatically moved to the trash.

Comment: Thanks but AppZapper seems to lack an initial system scan as well. Hazel looks neat and I might have a use for it doing other stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

[Fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) tracks what happens when software is installed, and displays this graphically. Uninstalling would be largely manual, but should be straightforward enough.

Comment: Wow, I'm a bit OCD about what's on my system and this looks very useful :) Thanks!