# Best free application uninstaller on Mac

Tags: mac, software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any recommendations for a before&after software installation scanner/uninstaller?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10913/any-recommendations-for-a-beforeafter-software-installation-scanner-uninstaller)

What is the best *free* software "uninstaller" for OS X?

Answer (score 7):

### [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/) (free)

Delete applications using drag and drop. Protects system applications.

Smart Delete finds additional files when dropping a program to the trash.

You can also delete widgets and plug-ins using this tool.

Comment: Agreed. AppCleaner works well for me.

Comment: Third here. Just make sure to go to Preferences and activate "Smart Delete". Every time you then trash an app it auto-launches AppCleaner, which is awesome.

Comment: Yes I also use AppCleaner and find it very effective

Answer (score 6):

### [Your Hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6YD5.jpg) (free)

Drag to the trash.

Comment: This is not necessarily a good way because applications leave things around (eg in ~/Library/Application Support) which then justwaste space on your hard drive. Since it's difficult to find and delete them all manually, it's easier to use an application for it.

Comment: Yeah, apps leave thing in Application Support, Preferences and so on. But "space waste"... ;) Maybe you lose 1-2GB in a year - not a big deal, after a while you will upgrade your HDD to bigger or will buy a new notebook. So, *usually* dragging app into Trash is enough. ;)

Comment: Sure, but those Apps make it *very* easy to properly clean things up and in some circumstances it can be a lot more than "1-2 GB in a year", just think of uninstalling Steam by dragging it to the trash. Unless you know where to delete the game files manually, you'll lose 10s of GB of space for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

### [TrashMe](http://www.jibapps.com/products/trashme/) (free)

It does a good job of finding dependencies in odd places without having to do any contact file system monitoring. Also handles widgets, preference pane add-ons and Safari plugins.