# Which is the best Mac App Cleaner

Tags: applications, macos

Which is the best App Cleaner for Mac. I'm using [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) at the moment.

Have you other preferences?

Comment: By "app cleaner" do you mean app deleter?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes i do. App Deleter.

Comment: In that case, see these: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/15960/  http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/10913/